# What is the difference between String.slice and String.substring?

Tags: javascript, substring, slice, substr

Does anyone know what the difference is between these two methods?

```
String.prototype.slice
String.prototype.substring
```

Comment: It's an example of the poor design of JavaScript that we ended up with three methods that all do the same thing, but with different quirks. IMO `slice` is the one with the least unexpected behaviour.

Comment: IMO substring when used to take a substring from idx till end is more understandable at a glance. Especially to noobs

Comment: According to [this website](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2159-Using-Slice-Substring-And-Substr-In-Javascript.htm), `slice` can actually replace `substring` and there is no reason to use it.

Comment: The `slice` & `substring` methods are all most the same; except the that the `slice()` accepts a negative index, relative to the end of the string, but not the `substring`, it throws `out-of-bound` error

Comment: @AmolMKulkarni Not true at all. If you try `var a = "asdf".substring(-1);`, it's treated as `var a = "asdf".substring(0);`. There's no exception thrown. And if you use `var a = "asdf".substring(2, -1);`, it uses `0` in place of `-1` (like before), and swaps the arguments so it acts like `var a = "asdf".substring(0, 2);`. I even tried these on IE 8 and got the results with no exceptions

Comment: "I even tried these on IE 8" - I love programming.

Comment: Take a look at this MDN section answering this question: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring#differences_between_substring_and_slice

Answer (score 1177):

`slice()` works like `substring()` with a few different behaviors.

```
Syntax: string.slice(start, stop);
Syntax: string.substring(start, stop);
```

**What they have in common:**

1. If `start` equals `stop`: returns an empty string
2. If `stop` is omitted: extracts characters to the end of the string
3. If either argument is greater than the string's length, the string's length will be used instead.

**Distinctions of** [`substring()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)**:**

1. If `start > stop`, then `substring` will swap those 2 arguments.
2. If either argument is negative or is `NaN`, it is treated as if it were `0`.

**Distinctions of** [`slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice)**:**

1. If `start > stop`, `slice()` will return the empty string. (`""`)
2. If `start` is negative: sets char from the end of string, exactly like `substr()`.
3. If `stop` is negative: sets stop to: `string.length – Math.abs(stop)` (original value), except bounded at 0 (thus, `Math.max(0, string.length + stop)`) as covered in the [ECMA specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#sec-string.prototype.slice).

Source: [Rudimentary Art of Programming & Development: Javascript: substr() v.s. substring()](http://rapd.wordpress.com/2007/07/12/javascript-substr-vs-substring/)

Comment: In your last note on `slice()`, it should be `string.length - stop`

Comment: In your last note on `slice()`, I think it should be `(string.length – 1) + stop` or, to make it clear that it's negative, `(string.length – 1) – Math.abs(stop)`

Comment: @Longpoke: `String.slice` was added so that there is a string method consistent to `Array.slice`. `substring` has been there forever, so they didn’t break it and added another method. Hardly a crappy decision as 1. consistency is nice and 2. it allows CoffeeScript’s slicing syntax to work on arrays and strings. @Oriol: edited it in.

Comment: It seems there's a performance difference between substring and slice in Firefox 22.  http://jsperf.com/string-slice-vs-substring

Comment: They are equaly fast in Chrome as of May 2014.

Comment: I like how `substring` allows for interchangeable arguments.

Comment: Andy was right. `stop` will be set to `string.length + stop` if `stop` is negative. Remember `stop` is the index after the last character extracted!

Comment: @DanielVassallo You should really edit it. It's wrong.

Comment: It looks like point 5 on `substr` is incorrect, according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr):

"If start is negative, substr() uses it as a character index from the end of the string. If start is negative and abs(start) is larger than the length of the string, substr() uses 0 as the start index."

Comment: The last #3 point in the answer above is verifiably incorrect, but the author is not fixing it. Proof: `"abc".slice(0, -1)` equals `"ab"`, NOT `"a"` as his answer indicates.

Comment: Wow, how come nobody spotted that so far? The statement "If `start > stop`, `slice()` will return the empty string" is wrong. For example: `4 > -1`, but `"babayaga".slice(4, -1)` returns `"yag"`.

Comment: @goodvibration So the problem with the answer is that rule #3 should go first or should be noted as an exception to rule #1.

Answer (score 185):

### TL;DR:

- If you know the index (the position) on which you'll stop (but NOT include), use `slice()`.
- If you know the length of characters to be extracted, you *could* use `substr()`, but that is discouraged as it is deprecated.

Otherwise, read on for a full comparison

#### Syntax

- `string.slice(start,end)`
- `string.substr(start,length)`
- `string.substring(start,end)`

**Note #1**: `slice()==substring()`

#### What it does?

- `slice()` extracts parts of a string and returns the extracted parts in a new string.
- `substr()` extracts parts of a string, beginning at the character at the specified position, and returns the specified number of characters.
- `substring()` extracts parts of a string and returns the extracted parts in a new string.

**Note #2**: `slice()==substring()`

#### Changes the Original String?

- `slice()` doesn't
- `substr()` doesn't
- `substring()` doesn't

**Note #3**: `slice()==substr()==substring()`

#### Using Negative Numbers as an Argument

- `slice()` selects characters starting from the end of the string
- `substr()` selects characters starting from the end of the string
- `substring()` doesn't perform

**Note #4**: `slice()==substr()`

#### If the First Argument is Greater than the Second

- `slice()` doesn't perform
- `substr()` since the Second Argument is NOT a position, but length value, it will perform as usual, with no problems
- `substring()` will swap the two arguments, and perform as usual

#### The First Argument

- `slice()` required; starting Index
- `substr()` required; starting Index
- `substring()` required; starting Index

**Note #5**: `slice()==substr()==substring()`

#### The Second Argument

- `slice()` optional; the position (up to, but not including) where to end the extraction
- `substr()` optional; the number of characters to extract
- `substring()` optional; the position (up to, but not including) where to end the extraction

**Note #6**: `slice()==substring()`

#### What if the Second Argument is Omitted?

- `slice()` selects all characters from the start-position to the end of the string
- `substr()` selects all characters from the start-position to the end of the string
- `substring()` selects all characters from the start-position to the end of the string

**Note #7**: `slice()==substr()==substring()`

So, you can say that there's a difference between `slice()` and `substr()`, while `substring()` is basically a copy of `slice()`.

If you want `substr`'s functionality:

```
"foobarbaz".substr(index, length);
```

without using a deprecated feature, you can just do:

```
"foobarbaz".substring(index, length + index);
```

And get the exact same results bar all of the edge-cases, like negative index/length.

Comment: substr() should not be used https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr

Comment: @Killy [Source regarding it being a legacy feature](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) Not mentioned in your link.

Comment: You summarize your lengthy answer by "substring() is basically a copy of slice()", but the question was precisely about the difference between these two. The rest of your answer misses the topic, apart the *only* relevant piece information "slice will swap the arguments" hidden somewhere in the middle.

Comment: @CodeFinity when I wrote the post there was a comment about, but somebody removed it in july 2020 https://web.archive.org/web/20200704195437/https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr

Comment: @Killy: It is still in the compatibility table as well as the side-bar. There is inconsistency in the banners. No idea why someone removed it from one but not the others or vice versa. The inconsistency is a bit unfortunate. Banner is present on all the others. In short `substr` is part of Annex B of the ECMA standard hence not mart of the core. It gives a note for it's usage: https://262.ecma-international.org/9.0/#sec-additional-ecmascript-features-for-web-browsers - MDN note: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Deprecated_and_obsolete_features#string_methods

Comment: @CodeFinity: My comment above for you as well :), was no room left. Here is link to current ECMA draft as well: https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-additional-ecmascript-features-for-web-browsers - guess the removal of banner is due to «probably won't be removed anytime soon» in MDN link. I still find the inconsistency a bit unfortunate – should perhaps be another banner for similar cases (where not legacy, but likely to remain for quite a while.) – Personally I just realized it after the fact and am in the process of refactoring 1k lines of new code from substr to slice lol.

Answer (score 42):

Ben Nadel has written a good article about this, he points out the difference in the parameters to these functions:

```
String.slice( begin [, end ] )
String.substring( from [, to ] )
String.substr( start [, length ] )
```

He also points out that if the parameters to slice are negative, they reference the string from the end. Substring and substr doesn't.

[Here is his article](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2159-using-slice-substring-and-substr-in-javascript.htm) about this.

Comment: This is incorrect, substr does handle negative parameters.  `'0123456789'.substr(-3, 2) -> '78'`

Comment: about substr from mdn "Deprecated. Not for use in new websites."

Answer (score 18):

The one answer is fine but requires a little reading into.  Especially with the new terminology "stop".

My Go -- organized by differences to make it useful in addition to the first answer by Daniel above:

1) negative indexes.  Substring requires positive indexes and will set a negative index to 0.  Slice's negative index means the position from the end of the string.

```
"1234".substring(-2, -1) == "1234".substring(0,0) == ""
"1234".slice(-2, -1) == "1234".slice(2, 3) == "3"
```

2) Swapping of indexes.  Substring will reorder the indexes to make the first index less than or equal to the second index.

```
"1234".substring(3,2) == "1234".substring(2,3) == "3"
"1234".slice(3,2) == ""
```

### --------------------------

General comment -- I find it weird that the second index is the position after the last character of the slice or substring.  I would expect "1234".slice(2,2) to return "3".  This makes Andy's confusion above justified -- I would expect "1234".slice(2, -1) to return "34".  Yes, this means I'm new to Javascript.  This means also this behavior:

```
"1234".slice(-2, -2) == "", "1234".slice(-2, -1) == "3", "1234".slice(-2, -0) == "" <-- you have to use length or omit the argument to get the 4.
"1234".slice(3, -2) == "", "1234".slice(3, -1) == "", "1234".slice(3, -0) == "" <-- same issue, but seems weirder.
```

My 2c.

Answer (score 15):

The difference between `substring` and `slice` - is how they work with negative and overlooking lines abroad arguments:

### substring(start, end)

Negative arguments are interpreted as zero. Too large values ​​are truncated to the length of the string:

```
alert("testme".substring(-2)); // "testme", -2 becomes 0
```

Furthermore, if **start** > **end**, the arguments are interchanged, i.e. plot line returns between the start and end:

```
alert("testme".substring(4, -1)); // "test"
// -1 Becomes 0 -> got substring (4, 0)
// 4> 0, so that the arguments are swapped -> substring (0, 4) = "test"
```

### slice

Negative values ​​are measured from the end of the line:

```
alert("testme".slice(-2)); // "me", from the end position 2
alert("testme".slice(1, -1)); // "estm", from the first position to the one at the end.
```

It is much more convenient than the strange logic `substring`.

A negative value of the first parameter to substr supported in all browsers except IE8-.

If the choice of one of these three methods, for use in most situations - it will be `slice`: negative arguments and it maintains and operates most obvious.

Answer (score 3):

The only difference between slice and substring method is of arguments

Both take two arguments e.g. start/from and end/to.

You cannot pass a negative value as first argument for **substring** method but for **slice** method to traverse it from end.

Slice method argument details:

**Arguments**

**start_index**
Index from where slice should begin. If value is provided in negative it means start from last. e.g. -1 for last character.
**end_index**
Index after end of slice. If not provided slice will be taken from start_index to end of string. In case of negative value index will be measured from end of string.

Substring method argument details:

**Arguments**

**from**
It should be a non negative integer to specify index from where sub-string should start.
**to**
An optional non negative integer to provide index before which sub-string should be finished.

Answer (score 3):

substr: It's providing us to fetch part of the string based on specified index.
syntax of substr-
   string.substr(start,end)
   start - start index tells where the fetching start.
   end - end index tells upto where string fetches. It's optional.

slice: It's providing to fetch part of the string based on the specified index. It's allows us to specify positive and index.
syntax of slice - string.slice(start,end)
   start - start index tells where the fetching start.It's 
   end - end index tells upto where string fetches. It's optional.
  In 'splice' both start and end index helps to take positive and negative index.

sample code for 'slice' in string

```
var str="Javascript";
console.log(str.slice(-5,-1));

output: crip
```

sample code for 'substring' in string

```
var str="Javascript";
console.log(str.substring(1,5));

output: avas
```

[*Note: negative indexing starts at the end of the string.]

Comment: What you wrote is wrong AND not relevant for the question. substr() is a different function, it does NOT have parameters "start, stop" as you erroneously state in your answer: it has parameters "start, length". But the question is not at all about substr()! Fortunately a correct and complete answer was already given 9 years before...

Answer (score 0):

For `slice(start, stop)`, if `stop` is negative, `stop` will be set to:

```
string.length – Math.abs(stop)
```

rather than:

```
string.length – 1 – Math.abs(stop)
```