# How to output numbers with leading zeros in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, text-formatting, number-formatting

Is there a way to prepend leading zeros to numbers so that it results in a string of fixed length? For example, `5` becomes `"05"` if I specify 2 places.

Comment: I've found [this](http://www.codigomanso.com/en/2010/07/simple-javascript-formatting-zero-padding/) wich I guess is far more simple: `("00" + h).slice (-3);`

Comment: @PauloBueno `("00" + 1234).slice (-3);` gives `234` i.e. discards the most significant figure.

Comment: @DanielEarwicker sure it does but you should adjust to the ammount of digits you are expecting. `("000" + 1234).slice(-4)`, `("0000" + 12345).slice(-5)` and so on...

Comment: If you also want to limit the length of the number you could use this: `return (num/Math.pow(10,size)).toFixed(size).split('.')[1];`

Comment: To use @loafer solution without knowing in advance the maximum length of your number, you should first use the following: `size = ('' + num).length;` (for positive integer values)

Comment: I also like @loafer's approach, but it doesn't work if the number has more digits than the intended size. This seems to work better:
`(num/Math.pow(10, size) + '').replace(/0{0,1}\./m, '')`. Keep in mind that both solutions only work for integers.

Comment: Now javascript supports [padStart](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart): `(5).toString().padStart(3, "0")`.

Comment: A simple one-liner using ternary logic: `num < 10 ?  num = '0'+num : null`

Comment: ECMA2017 lets you use `num.toString().padStart(5,'0')` which will pad a number to be of length 5. (ie `33` becomes `00033`)

Comment: `zeroPad = (num, size) => "0".repeat(size -1) + num;`

Answer (score 969, accepted):

> *NOTE*: Potentially outdated. ECMAScript 2017 includes [`String.prototype.padStart`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart).

You'll have to convert the number to a string since numbers don't make sense with leading zeros. Something like this:

```
function pad(num, size) {
    num = num.toString();
    while (num.length < size) num = "0" + num;
    return num;
}
```

Or, if you know you'd never be using more than X number of zeros, this might be better. This assumes you'd never want more than 10 digits.

```
function pad(num, size) {
    var s = "000000000" + num;
    return s.substr(s.length-size);
}
```

If you care about negative numbers you'll have to strip the `-` and read it.

Comment: Second function; shorter:
```function pad(num, size){
    return ('000000000' + num).substr(-size);
}```

Comment: ^ Negative values won't work in many versions of IE.

Comment: Ah, apparently slice() works with negative values in IE though :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2243824/what-is-the-difference-between-string-slice-and-string-substring-in-javascript

Comment: Perhaps an example how to call the function and result?

Comment: figured it out: value = pad(value, 18); ==> always returns 18 characters, so if you add 10 zero's size should be 10.

Comment: It's even nicer if you use spaces instead of 0s.

Comment: The second function is 5 times faster. http://js.do/code/padding

Comment: ES6: const pad = (n, s) => ('000000000' + n).substr(-s);

Comment: Another option is to convert the number to a string by locale and specify the minimum number of integer digits `num.toLocaleString(undefined, { minimumIntegerDigits: size })` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString

Comment: Uhm, just of curiosity, the first version (with `while (s.length < size) s = "0" + s;`) seems to have quadratic run time (i.e. O(N^2)) - is it something about string concatenation in JS that I don't know, or no one really cares about asymptotic complexity in JS anymore? :)

Comment: The first argument preserves the number if it's longer than the padding, and the second will truncate the number. So `pad("123",2)` will give `123` for the first and `23` for the second.

Comment: Here's a lighter version:
`function pad(n, t) {
    for (n = n.toString(); n.length < t;) n = "0" + n;
    return n
}`

Comment: substr() is considered deprecated, use substring() instead :)

Comment: Using num+"" is safer than .toString()

Answer (score 637):

**UPDATE:** Small one-liner function using the ES2017 [`String.prototype.padStart`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart) method:

```js
const zeroPad = (num, places) => String(num).padStart(places, '0')

console.log(zeroPad(5, 2)); // "05"
console.log(zeroPad(5, 4)); // "0005"
console.log(zeroPad(5, 6)); // "000005"
console.log(zeroPad(1234, 2)); // "1234"
```

Another ES5 approach:

```
function zeroPad(num, places) {
  var zero = places - num.toString().length + 1;
  return Array(+(zero > 0 && zero)).join("0") + num;
}

zeroPad(5, 2); // "05"
zeroPad(5, 4); // "0005"
zeroPad(5, 6); // "000005"
zeroPad(1234, 2); // "1234" :)
```

Comment: You're not taking into account negative array sizes ;) eg `zeroPad(1234, 2)` -> `RangeError: Invalid array length`

Comment: According to this benchmark, this method is 5 times slower than the accepted solution: https://gist.github.com/4382935

Comment: I like the code, but it does seem to be slower in Chrome. Interested in seeing results from other browsers: http://jsperf.com/zero-padding-number-methods

Comment: For Node.js this is the best working solution. GJ

Comment: If you're slow like me the argument for `num` in the `.padStart` call is NOT the length to pad with but the maximum length to pad to. Important distinction.

Comment: `zeroPad(1.2, 5)` -> `'001.2'`

Answer (score 268):

You could extend the `Number` object:

```
Number.prototype.pad = function(size) {
    var s = String(this);
    while (s.length < (size || 2)) {s = "0" + s;}
    return s;
}
```

*Examples:*

```
(9).pad();  //returns "09"

(7).pad(3);  //returns "007"
```

Comment: I think this is just what I need. The argument 'size' refers to the FINAL character count and not the total number of zeros to add, right?

Comment: yeah, it does, it checks the total length and compares that.

Comment: Yeah, it depends on where you are using it. It is not inherently bad thing, but if used in a space with lots of third party involvement, potentially a risk with overwriting functionality.

Comment: `(9).pad()` and `(7).pad(3)` with parens!

Comment: @Adam have you seen the date of the article? so this will not perform well in IE6, :scream:! Thanks Mild.

Comment: The problem is not comparable to globals, nor does it have anything to do with IE6. The problem is perpetual. The fact that it was discovered years ago doesn’t make it go away. The problem is that the language itself evolves. Who’s to say your `.pad()` will work the same way as a native version, should it ever come along?

I can’t find my original comment. Hopefully it’s just a bug in Stack Overflow. If it was deleted, that would be a poor reflection of the state of things around here.

Comment: This answer was written a long time ago, but I would say that I think there is a delightful elegance in extended prototypes. I understand the risks, and I never do this on client work but I do like it. The risk can be mitigated by name spacing, calling it _myPad or something.

Comment: But yeah, if you don't fully understand the risks, do not do this.

Comment: Performance of extended function will be less then simple function. So do not extend prototypes.

Answer (score 69):

From https://gist.github.com/1180489

```
function pad(a, b){
  return(1e15 + a + '').slice(-b);
}
```

With comments:

```
function pad(
  a, // the number to convert 
  b // number of resulting characters
){
  return (
    1e15 + a + // combine with large number
    "" // convert to string
  ).slice(-b) // cut leading "1"
}
```

Comment: This is good but it has a fatal flaw. For example, `pad (1234, 3) === "234"`! Which is obviously, unacceptable.

Comment: It's also broken if you want padding longer than 15. Elegant, but pretty inflexible.

Comment: @dave1010 I got a bad result `pad(1234)` yields `"1000000000001234"`  .  with parameter `pad(1234,20)` yields `"1000000000001234"` Thanks @Brock Adams

Comment: @JamesThomasMoon1979, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1268377/331508).  Not only does it work properly (while most other answers fail many test cases), it significantly outperforms the other approaches -- especially if you use the logarithmic variation linked in the comments.

Comment: @BrockAdams My test case is in my prior comment.  It did not work properly.  Tested on firefox 35 on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 15):

```
function zfill(num, len) {return (Array(len).join("0") + num).slice(-len);}
```

Comment: When you post code select it and click on the `{}` button so it gets formatted as such.

Comment: zfill(1234, 3) === "234"

Comment: function zFill(n,l){return (l>n.toString().length)?((Array(l).join('0')+n).slice(-l)):n;}

Answer (score 5):

Just for fun (I had some time to kill), a more sophisticated implementation which caches the zero-string:

```
pad.zeros = new Array(5).join('0');
function pad(num, len) {
    var str = String(num),
        diff = len - str.length;
    if(diff <= 0) return str;
    if(diff > pad.zeros.length)
        pad.zeros = new Array(diff + 1).join('0');
    return pad.zeros.substr(0, diff) + str;
}
```

If the padding count is large and the function is called often enough, it actually outperforms the other methods...