# Adding zeros when length is less

Tags: javascript

Is there a smart way to convert numbers to string and automatically add zeroes so the length is the same as the maximum?

like this:

```
for (var i=0; i<30; i++) {
    var c = i.toString();
    if (c.length == 1) {
        c = '0'+=c;
    }
}
```

But smarter

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to output integers with leading zeros in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998784/how-to-output-integers-with-leading-zeros-in-javascript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a million ways, this is one of them, and its actually quite efficient too..

**UPDATE 2**
Here's code for the 'third interpretation of the OP's question

This will output ["00", "01", "02" .... ,"30"]

```
var max = 30, i = max, maxLength = max.toString().length, num,  zeroes=[];
while (i--) zeroes.push("0");
zeroes = zeroes.join();

for (i=0; i < max ; i++) {
    num = i.toString();
    console.log(zeroes.substring(0, maxLength - num.length) + num);
}
```

**UPDATE 1** adapted the code for both 'possible' interpretations of the OP's question.

If what you want is code that based on n=5 , max = 30 produces 29 "0"s followed by "5" then this is the code you want

```
var n = 5, max = 30;

var a = n.toString().split(), zeroesToAdd = max - a.length;
while(zeroesToAdd--) a.unshift("0");
var num = a.join("");

alert(num);​
```

If what you want is code that based on n=5 , max = 30 produces 2 (the length of 30.toString()) "0"s followed by "5" then this is the code you want

```
var n = 5, maxLength = (30).toString().length;

var a = n.toString().split(), zeroesToAdd = maxLength - a.length;
while(zeroesToAdd--) a.unshift("0");
var num = a.join("");

alert(num);​
```

The only difference here is in the first line.

These do not use string concatenation (extremely inefficient), instead they use `Array.unshift` and `Array.join`

Comment: This is definitely clever, but I'm under the impression that you are adding 30 "0"s, wouldn't max need to be 2 (the number of places)?

Comment: No, I'm adding 29 (30 - "5".length). This is according to the OP's request as far as I can see

Comment: What's the purpose of the `split()` there?  Doesn't that just return the original input right back?  (I know this is a small nitpick to a great answer; using `unshift()` here is brilliant.)

Comment: Firebug seems to be showing 29 leading zeros given the code above. Otherwise, nice work!

Comment: @sworoc Now, isn't the point of this to return a string the length of `max`? If so 29 "0"s and "5" is pretty much the correct answer isn't it?

Comment: @Lord It creates an array from the string, with each character in its own slot

Comment: I believe he's trying to print out the numbers 0 through 29, zero padded (single digit numbers have 1 leading 0). I think it's just a misreading of his loop that is causing issue.  His code and yours produce different output, though I agree that yours works in the general case.

Answer (score 4):

I think the fastest way to do it is without the loop.
Like that:

```js
var pad="000000";
var str="182"; //or any desired number here

var result=pad.slice(str.length)+str;
```

Result will be 000182. Let me know.

Michael

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure I understand what you mean by "smarter," but I did find this flexible zero-padding method (slightly modified due to @Sean's comment; in-code comments mine):

```
function PadDigits(n, totalDigits)
{
    n = n.toString();
    var pd = '';
    // Figure out if we need to pad at all
    if (totalDigits > n.length)
    {
        // Construct a string of as many leading zeroes as needed
        for (i = 0; i < (totalDigits-n.length); i++)
        {
            pd += '0'; // String concat for EACH leading zero; inefficient
        }
    }
    // Add the leading zeroes to the string representing the original number
    return pd + n; // Removed unnecessary toString() here
}
```

Source: http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/general/how-do-i-pad-digits-with-leading-zeros.html

Comment: Not too efficient, also, for some reason it calls toString twice on n

Answer (score 1):

you could ask mr. google for a javascript implementation of `sprintf()` wich might be useful in some other cases - but if you only have to do this one operation, such a function will be a bit too much overhead.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i=0; i<30; i++)
  var c = i < 10 ? '0'+i.toString() : i.toString() ;
```

Comment: What would you do if it was a 5 character field (10,000)?

How do you account for zero padding 100? 1000?

Comment: The loop given by the op is only between 0 and 30.

Comment: True, but smarter implies not needing to rewrite the whole thing to do 0 to 100, and in this case you would need two checks, one for < 10 and one for < 100.  Just sayin'

Answer (score 0):

```
var c=i.toString(), len=30-c.length;
while(len>0){
   c='0'+c;
   --len;
  }
```

Comment: `while(i--) { }` is a simpler approach, especially since you aren't using `i` for anything inside the block

Answer (score 0):

```
var zeroPad = "000";

for(var i=0; i<30; i++) {
 var output = zeroPad + i.toString();
 output.substr(output.length - 2);
}
```

If you vary the number of "0" in zeroPad, and change your length offset, this will work for however large you want (obviously within reason). Not the best, but it works and is simple.

Answer (score 0):

here is how to do it (parametric)

```
// number is the number you need to convert, and maxdigits is the total number of digits including the number
function leadingZeros( number, maxdigits )
{
 var number_text = number.toString();
 var number_len = number_text.length;

 for (var i=0;i<maxdigits-number_len;i++)
     number_text = '0'+number_text;

 return number_text;
}
// example leadingZeros(3,5)   will return 00003
// example leadingZeros(194,5) will return 00194
```

Answer (score 0):

With courtesy from [4GuysFromRolla](https://web.archive.org/web/20200801102155/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com:80/webtech/code/Right.shtml), for those used to VBScript:

```
var padd = "000000000000000000000000000000";
var sourceval = 100;

alert(Right(padd + sourceval, 30));

function Right(str, n)
{
    if (n <= 0)
    {
        return "";
    }

    if (n > String(str).length)
    {
        return str;
    }

    var iLen = String(str).length;
    return String(str).substring(iLen, iLen - n);
}
```

Comment: @nico Definitly not the best shot - @InfinitiesLoop has a better solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998784/how-to-output-integers-with-leading-zeros-in-javascript/2998822#2998822

... and @CMS does also have a good one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998784/how-to-output-integers-with-leading-zeros-in-javascript/2998874#2998874

I didn't flex that JavaScript muscle for quite some time ...

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to determine how many digits you will need, do a ceiling(log10) of the maximum number you are converting to a string, and that will tell you, assuming you don't have anything to the right of the decimal point.