# using date in javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I have trouble using date in Javascript, in PHP you use something like date("Y-m-d H:i s") to retrieve the specific date and time, how can I achieve this in Javascript? the getMonth() method only returns 1 digit, I really need them to be in 2 digits

Comment: so you pad: if (mm<10) mm="0"+mm;

Comment: Can you try my answer?

Comment: @mplungjan, i know man, i just want to let him know, that's it. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do i get Month and Date of Javascript in two digit format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6040515/how-do-i-get-month-and-date-of-javascript-in-two-digit-format)

Answer (score 1):

Since I made comments on almost all answers, I'd better post my suggestion

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/Yy7Ft/)

```
function pad(num) { return ("0"+num).slice(-2); }

function getDisplayDate() {
  var date = new Date();
  return date.getFullYear()+
    "-"+pad(date.getMonth()+1)+
    "-"+pad(date.getDate())+
    " "+pad(date.getHours())+
    ":"+pad(date.getMinutes())+
    ":"+pad(date.getSeconds());
}    
setInterval(function() {
    document.getElementById("time").innerHTML=getDisplayDate(); 
},500);
```

Answer (score 0):

why dont you add 0 before when you get <10

Comment: Choices .. :) ... I altered the code, which made your argument a valid addition. thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
function dateToYMD(date) {
var d = date.getDate();
var m = date.getMonth() + 1;
var y = date.getFullYear();
return '' + y + '-' + (m<=9 ? '0' + m : m) + '-' + (d <= 9 ? '0' + d : d) + ' ' + date.getHours() + ':' + date.getMinutes() + ':' + date.getSeconds();
}
var d = new Date();
alert(dateToYMD(d));
```

Comment: <10 saves 2 chars every time

Comment: you are missing the hours and minutes and seconds

Answer (score 0):

This code is adjusted based on the pointers given by @mplungjan -- (credits to him please)
Also check out his solution, which is a better one for use with date digits.

```
var str = 10; // month-digit from getMonth()

function pad(val) {
     return "0" + val;
}

var month =  str < 10 ? pad(str) : str;
console.log(month);
```

Comment: Well... I am not familiar with "pad" and can't find this back as a a native function, so you would still nee to declare this function.
I did alter my code to make it shorter .. :)

Comment: Well dear friend .. You write a function and return val and then return "0"+num. That already misses the "else" statement, so I apologize if I get confused. I just don't see what you are getting at. So all I can say is that I will appreciate your solution worked out. I am always open to learn new ways. Now you vote me down, but you offer me nothing new. If I overlook something, then please specify.

Comment: `function pad(num) { if (num>9) return num; return "0"+num}` - I was on my iPhone - a typo. No need for else when you return

Comment: I voted you down because you hugely complicated the issue, still use getMonthDigits when your function no longer is visibly related to month, do not define month and so on.

Comment: @mplungjan - Thanks. A valid point not to define "month". Omitting "else" is more a shortcut I see. A nice way to keep things short. Thanks.

Comment: Normally you would do `var a = ()?b:c` but you have complicated things with the abuse of the ternary side effects of `()?a=b:a=c`

Comment: @mplungjan - Thanks for the lesson. I adjusted the code to reflect on lessons learned and to eliminate the "horror".

Answer (score -2):

you can year, minutes, etc from Date class. You can get 2 digits month using some trick like example below. e.g

```
Date.prototype.getLongMonth = function() {
    var month = this.getMonth();
    if (String(month).length == 1) month = '0'.concat(month);
    return month;
}

var now = new Date();
var theDate = now.getFullYear() + '-' + now.getLongMonth() + '-' + now.getDate() + ' ' + now.getHours() + ':' + now.getMinutes() + ':' + now.getSeconds();
console.log(theDate); // result : 2013-02-17 12:41:2
```

Comment: He said now.getMonth() this will return month in 1 digit, he wants in 2 digits

Comment: That is a LOT more code than `if (mm<10) mm="0"+mm` and it is wrong because it will return 00 for January

Comment: Still wrong, still returns 00 for January... What use is that?

Comment: Somehow, i get 2013-02-17 1:56:59 instead of 2013-03-17 06:56 59

Comment: I've suggested to use the solution [("0" + (this.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6040556/295783)