# Change datepicker date format in beforeShowDay function

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using the beforeShowDay function to highlight days that match a MySQL query of 'used' dates.

My datepicker set-up looks like this:

```
dp = jQuery( "#datepicker" ).datepicker(
                                { 
                                    minDate: +1, 
    maxDate: "+1M",
    dateFormat: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
                                                          q = q_dates[date];
                                                    }
                                                }
                                                );
```

The problem is that the value of DATE looks like this: Mon May 27 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0700 (SE Asia Standard Time)

I've tried setting the dateFormat. Also tried date.toString('yyyy-mm-dd') thinking it would work like a Javascript date object.

How can I convert DATE to the format yyyy-mm-dd?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using [Date.js](http://www.datejs.com/) plugin.  Check out their [documentation](http://www.datejs.com/2007/11/27/getting-started-with-datejs/).

Also try using below code:

```
date.getFullYear() + "-" + date.getMonth() + "-" + date.getDate() ;
```

**EDIT:**

for 2 digit Date and month, I would suggest to have a look at this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6040556/1671639).

```
var date = new Date("Mon May 27 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0700 (SE Asia Standard Time)");

alert(date.getFullYear() + "-" + ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + "-" + ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2) );
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I saw the second one somewhere. But the month and date has to be in 2 digit formats, and I don't know of a quick and clean way to make that happen. And adding another plugin seems like overkill just to reformat the date in one place. I am really surprised there is not a simple formatting command that can be called to do this.

Comment: Thanks. I was just about to comment that I found a similar solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3605214/javascript-add-leading-zeroes-to-date

Comment: @Lee Usually it happen, when we search we won't be able to find the exact link.  After posting question, we will find the exact link for the answer :)

Comment: Yes, very true. It is almost embarrassing sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

No need for any extra plugin. Use the built-in jqueryui `formatDate();`

For all the different formats look here in their [docs](https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/date-formats.html)

For the sake of quality I'll post all date formats here

**Datepicker date formats**

```
"mm/dd/yy"
"yy-mm-dd"
"d M, y"
"d MM, y"
"DD, d MM, yy"
"'day' d 'of' MM 'in the year' yy"
```

**jqueryui**

```
//return today's date
$.datepicker.formatDate("yy-mm-dd", $('#datepicker').datepicker("getDate"));

//alternatively you can use this syntax
jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', 'getDate');
```

**Datepicker**

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
changeMonth: true,
changeYear: true,
beforeShowDay : function (date){

//format date
var jquerydate = $.datepicker.formatDate("yy-mm-dd", date);

//alternative syntax
var jquerydate = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);

}

});
```