# Hour and Minutes with javascript

Tags: javascript

I have made this with js:

```
// time

var date = new Date();

var currentTime = date.getHours() + ':' + date.getMinutes();

document.getElementById('timex').value = currentTime;
```

This script inserts the hour and minutes in a input.

There is a problem, at 16:06 the time becomes  16:6. And this causes a problem with the html input. The same thing happens at 1am. Become 1:34 and not 01:34.

Comment: Check if the value is less than 10, if so, insert a preceding zero.

Comment: PLEASE search google first next time you want to ask. This is not just a FAQ it is a FFAQ

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/a/6040556/7549867

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, simple and works like a charm:

```
var date = new Date();

var currentTime = ('0' + date.getHours()).slice(-2) + ':' + ('0' + date.getMinutes()).slice(-2);

document.getElementById('timex').value = currentTime;
```

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer, I would really appreciate it if you accept the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```
d.toISOString().substring(11).slice(0,5)
```