# Convert date string with timezone to format yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, locale

Hello I was wondering is it possible to transform this Date string:

`Sat Aug 12 2000 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Midden-Europese zomertijd)`

to the format of:

```
2000-08-12
```

I tried the following things:

```js
var DateInput = "Sat Aug 12 2000 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Midden-Europese zomertijd)";
var test = new Date(DateInput);
console.log(test);

var convert_date = test.toString().split('-');
console.log(convert_date);
```

But this does not work. Can anyone explain why and help me guiding to the right direction?

Comment: `test.getFullYear() + "-" + test.getDate() + "-" + ( test.getMonth()+1)`

Comment: You can't just do `new Date` that returns different results depending on locations, browser, etc. etc. See [Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results)

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you are really just trying to reformat the input date string (without converting to local time). Your attempt relies on `Date` for string parsing, which is not recommended (see [JavaScript Date note regarding date string parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Parameters)). It also uses `toString` which is implementation dependent and can't be relied on to reformat the output to a specific format like `yyyy-mm-dd`.

You can't just convert the date string to a `Date` object and then rely on methods like `getDate()` because those methods return values in local time which may be different than the date values you are trying to preserve from the input date string with a specific timezone.

As noted in other answers, there are lots of libraries you can use for this sort of thing. Otherwise, here are a couple of hacks you can try (beware, variations in your date string input format could break either of these approaches - hence the existence of the libraries).

Credit to [@SergeyMetlov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/377133/sergey-metlov) for the [two digit month and date formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6040515/how-do-i-get-month-and-date-of-javascript-in-2-digit-format#6040565).

If your date strings are consistently formatted in the same way as your example, just parse the string and reformat the output as desired.

```js
const str = 'Sat Aug 12 2000 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Midden-Europese zomertijd)';
const format = (d) => (d < 10 ? '0' : '') + d;
const months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];

// parse date string (lazy since time parts not used)
const [day, m, d, yyyy, ...time] = str.split(' ');

// two digit format for month and date
const mm = format(months.indexOf(m) + 1);
const dd = format(d);

// format date as yyyy-mm-dd
const date = `${yyyy}-${mm}-${dd}`;
console.log(date);
// 2000-08-12
```

Or if you want to force the js date object to submit, then you can try something ugly like the below. The example relies on `Date.parse` to parse the input date string which is not recommended since implementations may not be consistent across browsers. If you really wanted to do something like this you should replace `Date.parse` (and the clunky `substr` line) with some better parsing of your own.

```js
const str = 'Sat Aug 12 2000 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Midden-Europese zomertijd)';
const format = (d) => (d < 10 ? '0' : '') + d;
const utc = Date.parse(str);
const localoffset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset() * 60000;
const operator = str.substr(28, 1);
const stroffset = (() => {
  let offset = str.substr(29, 4) * 60000;
  if (operator === '-') {
    offset *= -1;
  }
  
  return offset;
})();

// convert utc to "wrong" date, will look "right" when formatted
const wrong = new Date(utc + localoffset + stroffset);
const y = wrong.getFullYear();
const m = format(wrong.getMonth() + 1);
const d = format(wrong.getDate());
const output = `${y}-${m}-${d}`;
console.log(output);
// 2000-08-12
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work `test.getFullYear() + "-" + test.getMonth()+1 + "-"  + test.getDate()`

Answer (score 0):

Use **date-fns** to manipulate dates, its very cool modern JavaScript date utility library

Ex:

```
var format = require('date-fns/format');
var result = format(new Date('Sat Aug 12 2000 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Midden-Europese zomertijd)'),'YYYY-DD-MM');
```

link: https://date-fns.org/v1.29.0/docs/format

Comment: You can't just do `new Date` that returns different results depending on locations, browser, etc. etc. See [Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results)

Answer (score 0):

I actually created this [dateFormat.js](https://gist.github.com/ajaypayne/f723a326dfc5996e3898e683723b9b48) to handle exactlly this sort of thing. It extends the Date object so as long as you have included the file in your site you can use

```
var date = new Date(); 
date.formatDateTime('YDM')
```

And by using the Date object, you can also set the date you wish to format as normal.

Comment: @Liam, while I would agree that it does appear good, moment.js does a lot more than just format dates, and for something this simple, it would be overkill to include the entire library. My answer gives a small amount of code that does the one thing that is being asked for.