# Passing of dates from jquery to html

Tags: jquery, django, bootstrap-4

I created a button linked with a `jquery` so that when I click on the `edit button` in my form, the data from the entry will be populated into the form as well.

The rest of the values do get populated into the form via `jquery`, however, my problem is with the `dates` value. Somehow, the `dates` are not being rendered into the form when passed back from `jquery`.

**html**

```
...
<button type="button" class="edit-current-policy-term float-right" 
    data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit-term-policy-modal" 
    data-term="{{ policy_period.term }}" 
    data-start_term="{{ policy_period.start_term }}" 
    data-end_term="{{ policy_period.end_term }}" 
    data-pk="{{ policy_period.pk }}">
    <i class="fas fa-edit"></i>
</button>
```

**jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('show.bs.modal', '#edit-term-policy-modal', function (event) {
        const button = $(event.relatedTarget); 
        let term = button.data('term'); 
        let start_term = button.data('start_term'); 
        let end_term = button.data('end_term'); 
        const pk = button.data('pk'); 

        const modal = $(this);                     
        modal.find('.modal-body #id_term_number').val(term);
        modal.find('.modal-body #id_start_term').val(start_term);
        modal.find('.modal-body #id_end_term').val(end_term);
    });
});
```

**forms**

```
class NewTermPolicyPeriodForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(NewTermPolicyPeriodForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['term'].widget = forms.TextInput(
        attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'id': 'id_term_number', 'name': 'term_number', 'type': 'number',
               'placeholder': 'Term number'})
        self.fields['term'].required = True

        self.fields['start_term'].widget = forms.DateInput(
        attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'id': 'id_start_term', 'name': 'start_term', 'type': 'date',
               'placeholder': 'Term start date'})
        self.fields['start_term'].required = True

        self.fields['end_term'].widget = forms.DateInput(
        attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'id': 'id_end_term', 'name': 'end_term', 'type': 'date',
               'placeholder': 'Term end date'})
        self.fields['end_term'].required = True

        self.fields['term_end'].widget = forms.CheckboxInput(
        attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'id': 'id_term_end', 'name': 'term_end'})
        self.fields['term_end'].required = False

    class Meta:
        model = TermPolicyPeriod
        fields = [
            'term', 'start_term', 'end_term', 'term_end'
        ]
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Are there errors in your console?

Comment: I've got some errors related to `non-unique-id` but these `id`s are not related to this `modal` or data in any way. Asides from this, there isn't any error in my console.

Comment: It seems like it. I did some test and it seems that `jquery` format is `YYYY-MM-DD` whereas if i `console.log(start_term)`, the console prints out: `Oct. 1, 2018`. Any ideas how I can be converting this to `jquery` `date object`?

Comment: Yes, that's actually the problem. Because the `data` attribute for the date is actually in `string` format. I used `console.log` and saw that it's in `string` format.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem with modification from this answer: [How do I get Month and Date of JavaScript in 2 digit format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6040515/how-do-i-get-month-and-date-of-javascript-in-2-digit-format)

Sample `jquery` code below:

```
.... 
    const button = $(event.relatedTarget);          
    let term = button.data('term');             
    let start_term = new Date(button.data('start_term'));
    let start_term_getMonth = ("0" + (start_term.getMonth() + 1).toString()).slice(-2);
    let start_term_getDate = ("0" + (start_term.getDate()).toString()).slice(-2);

    let end_term = new Date(button.data('end_term'));
    let end_term_getMonth = ("0" + (end_term.getMonth() + 1).toString()).slice(-2);
    let end_term_getDate = ("0" + (end_term.getDate()).toString()).slice(-2);
    const pk = button.data('pk');                   

    const end_term_date = end_term.getFullYear() + '-' + end_term_getMonth + '-' + end_term_getDate;
    const start_term_date = start_term.getFullYear() + '-' + start_term_getMonth + '-' + start_term_getDate;

    const modal = $(this);                          
    modal.find('.modal-body #id_term_number').val(term);
    modal.find('.modal-body #id_start_term').val(start_term_date);
    modal.find('.modal-body #id_end_term').val(end_term_date);    

    console.log(start_term_date, end_term_date);
```

The reason why you `+1` to `month` is because `Jan` starts from `00` instead of `01`. This is also done before it converts from `int` to `string` in the above code. Hope it makes sense for others who are facing this problem.