# How to parse the 2 values in from javascript into 2 input boxes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**Statement**

I would like to parse the value into 2 input boxes (lat and lng) after the user input location name and then click at <kbd>Convert</kbd>

I wonder if I used the wrong id selector to get/parse the value or there is more code.

**front.php**

```
<html>
<body>
<?php 
      include 'connection.php'; 
      require_once 'process.php';
?>

<form method="post" action="process.php">
  <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Date</label>:&nbsp&nbsp
                  <input style="font-size:22px" size="20" type="text" name="datetime" id="showTime"placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss" readonly required>
                  <button style="font-size:36px" type="button" name="Time" id="getTime"  class="btn btn-info round"><i class="far fa-clock"></i></button>
                  <h5 style="color:white">Please click at the Time button on the right to convert the location name <br> into latitude and longitude coordinates.</h5>
                  </div>
<!-----------------------------------Section B------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
                  <label>Enter Location name:</label>
                  <div id="locPost">
                  <input style="font-size:1em" size="32" type="text" name="locPost" placeholder="Please enter location name" required>
                  </div>
                  <h5 style="color:white">Please click at the Convert button below to convert the location name <br> into latitude and longitude coordinates.</h5>
                  <div style="text-align:center" id="getGPS">
                  <button style="font-size:1em" type="submit" name="Convert" class="btn btn-dark">Convert <i class="fas fa-location-arrow"></i></button> <!--There could be error here...-->
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group" id="showLat">
                  <label>Latitude</label>:&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
                  <input type="text" value="<?php echo $lat; ?>" name="lat" placeholder="Latitude" readonly>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group" id="showLong">
                  <label>Longitude</label>:&nbsp
                  <input type="text" value="<?php echo $lng; ?>" name="lng" placeholder="Longitude" readonly>
                  </div>
<!-------------------------------------End Section B------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->

</form>
<!--End form-->        

                 <div class="row" style="padding: 10px">
                      <div class="col">                                                      
                          <button style="font-size: 1em" type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="Save"><b>Save <i class="fas fa-save"></i></b></button>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col">
                          <button style="font-size: 1em" type="reset" class="btn btn-warning" value="Reset"><b>Reset <i class="fas fa-sync"></i></b></button>
                      </div>
               </div>
</body>
</html>
<!--End html-->

<script>
        //Get current time
        var today = new Date();
        //Date formatting ref : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6040515/how-do-i-get-month-and-date-of-javascript-in-2-digit-format/42389398
        var currentTimeValue = today.getFullYear()+'-'+ ((today.getMonth() < 9 ? '0':'') + (today.getMonth()+1)) +'-'+
        ((today.getDate() < 10 ? '0' :'') + today.getDate())+" "+ ((today.getHours() < 10 ? '0' :'') + today.getHours()) + ":" +
        ((today.getMinutes() < 10 ? '0' :'') + today.getMinutes()) + ":" + ((today.getSeconds() < 10 ? '0' :'') + today.getSeconds());

        //Parse the value to date button
        $("#getTime").click(function()
        {
          $("#showTime").val(currentTimeValue);
        })

        //<--Geocode ref: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pRiQeo17u6c-->
        // Get location form
        var locationForm = document.getElementById('locPost');

        function geocode(e)
        {
          // Prevent actual submit
          e.preventDefault();
          var location = document.getElementById('getGPS').value; //Location-input
          axios.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json',
          {
            params:
            {
              address:location,
              key:'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' //Google API KEY
            }
          })
         .then(function(response)
          {
              // Geometry
              var lat = response.data.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
              var lng = response.data.results[0].geometry.location.lng;

              // Output to app
              document.getElementById('showLat').innerHTML = lat;
              document.getElementById('showLong').innerHTML = lng;
          })
        }
</script>
<!--End script-->
```

**process.php**

```
<?php
           session_start();
           include 'connection.php';         

           if(isset($_POST['Save']))
        {
           $rowcount=0;

           $category = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['category'] );
           $url = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['url'] );
           $datetime = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['datetime'] );
           $lat = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['lat'] );
           $lng = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['lng'] );

           $sql="SELECT crimenews_url FROM crimenews WHERE crimenews_url=?";
           $stmt=$conn->prepare( $sql );
           $stmt->bind_param('s',$url );
           $result=$stmt->execute();
           $stmt->store_result();
           $rowcount=$stmt->num_rows;
           $stmt->free_result();
           $stmt->close();

            $sql="INSERT INTO crimenews
            (crimenews_cat, crimenews_url, crimenews_datetime, crimenews_locationLat, crimenews_locationLong)
             VALUES( ?,?,?,?,? ) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE crimenews_url = VALUES(crimenews_url)";

             $stmt = $conn->prepare( $sql );
             $stmt->bind_param( "sssss", $category, $url, $datetime, $lat, $lng );
             $result = $stmt->execute();

             //There is duplicate input
             if($rowcount==1)
             {
                  $_SESSION['message'] = "The news has already existed.";
                  $_SESSION['msg_type'] = "danger";
             }
             //There is no duplicate input
             else
             {
                  $_SESSION['message'] = "The news has added.";
                  $_SESSION['msg_type'] = "success";
             }

             $stmt->close();
             header("location: front.php");
         }
?>
```

**Expecting Result**

In section B, after the user input location name `<div id=locPost>` and the user click at the <kbd>Convert</kbd> (`div id=getGPS`).

The value of lat and lng (from the script) will be parsed into `<div id=showLat>` and `<div id=showLong>` respectively.

After click at the <kbd>Save</kbd> button these values will parsed into MySQL server.

Comment: Your question code example is too complexity. Would you dry it & and make more readable, using the right indentations?

Comment: Where are controls with id's "showLat" and "showLong" ?  I cant see them in your html.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what your question is, but the problems I see with you're code is you have the wrong selector for `document.getElementById('getGPS').innerHtml` it should be

```js
document.querySelector("#locPost > input").value
```

or

```js
document.getElementById('locPost').children[0].value
```

and you have to get the right element after selecting the `div`, f.ex:

```html
<div class="form-group" id="showLat">
   <label>Latitude</label>:&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&
   <input type="text" value="<?php echo $lat; ?>" name="lat" placeholder="Latitude" readonly>
</div>
```

you would have to either use

```js
document.querySelector("#showLat> input").value
```

or

```js
document.getElementById('showLat').children[1].value
```

Basically, you're using the wrong selectors.

Comment: What do children[1].value in the last few lines mean?

Comment: Since inside the div "showLat" there are two HTML elements (label and input), you want showLat's second child element