# Show a leading zero if a number is less than 10

Tags: javascript, math, numbers, digits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript equivalent to printf/string.format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610406/javascript-equivalent-to-printf-string-format)
>   [How can I create a Zerofilled value using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267283/how-can-i-create-a-zerofilled-value-using-javascript)

I have a number in a variable:

```
var number = 5;
```

I need that number to be output as 05:

```
alert(number); // I want the alert to display 05, rather than 5.
```

How can I do this?

I could manually check the number and add a 0 to it as a string, but I was hoping there's a JS function that would do it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267283/how-can-i-create-a-zerofilled-value-using-javascript

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998784/how-to-output-integers-with-leading-zeros-in-javascript

Comment: function zeroFill(n,l){return ('0000000000'+n).slice(-l);}

Answer (score 190, accepted):

There's no built-in JavaScript function to do this, but you can write your own fairly easily:

```
function pad(n) {
    return (n < 10) ? ("0" + n) : n;
}
```

---

## EDIT:

Meanwhile there is a native JS function that does that. See [String#padStart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart)

```js
console.log(String(5).padStart(2, '0'));
```

Comment: Or `...n < 10 && n >=0...`, so you don't end up with "0-5".

Comment: Taking care of negavite upto 10 as well:
            
           function pad(n) {
                if (n < 10 & n >=0)
                    return ("0" + n);
                if(n < 0 & n > -11)
                    return ("-0" + Math.abs(n));
                return n;
            }

Comment: Nice one about the `padStart()` function.

Comment: FYI, according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart Internet Explorer does not support `padStart`.

Answer (score 12):

**Try this**

```
function pad (str, max) {
  return str.length < max ? pad("0" + str, max) : str;
}

alert(pad("5", 2));
```

Example

[http://jsfiddle.net/](http://jsfiddle.net/GmyHQ/)

**Or**

```
var number = 5;
var i;
if (number < 10) {
    alert("0"+number);
}
```

Example

[http://jsfiddle.net/](http://jsfiddle.net/Q5LPR/)

Comment: read his last sentence...he knows how to do that already, he was looking for a format function i believe.