# Dealing with products serial numbers (ID)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, web-applications

I want to save products serial numbers, I created a table

```
dbo.tStock
productType tinyint,
IdProduct int, 
ItemTypeNum tinyint, 
FirstSNum  nchar (20), 
LastSNum   nchar (20), 
TotalQty   bigint
```

when the user insert the `totalQty` and the first Serial Number `FirstSNum` the application should calculate the last serial number in squence.
In my page i used javascript function:

```
function Calculate() {
            var txt1 = document.getElementById('<%= txtTotalQty.ClientID%>').value
            var txt2 = document.getElementById('<%= txtFirstserial.ClientID%>').value
            if (txt1 != '' && txt2 != "")
                document.getElementById('<%= txtLastSerial.ClientID%>').value = 
                eval((parseFloat(txt1)-1 + parseFloat(txt2)))
        }
```

The problem is when the serial number start with zero (leading zero) I got a wrong calculation,eg:
 **totalQty:** 100
**Firstserial:** 01000
**LastSerial:** 1099 (**WRONG**) it should be=01099

I'm using ASP.NET C#,
 any idea? I appreciate any efforts ;-)

Comment: could http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998784/how-to-output-integers-with-leading-zeros-in-javascript be useful ?

Comment: It's usefull! thanks @F.Calderan , I mixed it with Andrew Leach answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`eval((parseFloat(txt1)-1 + parseFloat(txt2)))`

You don't need `eval()`. Just add the values.

`parseFloat()` does exactly what it says on the tin. It converts a string `"01000"` into a number: `1000`. So you end up with just a number, and numbers don't have leading zeroes.

If you want to zero-pad the resulting number, you need to do that yourself.

`("00000" + (parseFloat(txt1)-1 + (parseFloat(txt2))).toString()).substr(-5,5);`

Do your calculation, convert it to a string, prepend "00000" to it and then take the right-most five characters.

Comment: thanks, The length of each SN should be 15 digits, I think _substr()_ used to replace an existing, So I used:  zeropad((  (parseFloat(txt1)-1 + (parseFloat(txt2))).toString()),15) from the above link  function pad(num, size) {
    var s = num+"";
    while (s.length < size) s = "0" + s;
    return s;
}

Comment: If you want fifteen digits, just use fifteen digits: `("000000000000000" + (parseFloat(txt1)-1 + (parseFloat(txt2))).toString()).substr(-15,15)`;