# Modify element background color depending on date

Tags: jquery

I've a list of days like this,

```
<ul>
    <li class="dark"><a rel="25" class="0725" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">25</a></li>
    <li class="dark"><a rel="26" class="0726" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">26</a></li>
    <li class="dark"><a rel="27" class="0727" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">27</a></li>
    <li class="dark"><a rel="28" class="0728" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">28</a></li>
    <li class="dark"><a rel="29" class="0729" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">29</a></li>
    <li class="dark"><a rel="30" class="0730" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">30</a></li>
    <li class="dark first"><a rel="31" class="0731" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">31</a></li>
    <li class="dark"><a rel="1" class="0801" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">1</a></li>
    <li class="dark"><a rel="2" class="0802" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">2</a></li>
    <li class="dark"><a rel="3" class="0803" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">3</a></li>
    <li class="dark"><a rel="4" class="0804" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">4</a></li>
    <li class="dark"><a rel="5" class="0805" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">5</a></li>
    <li class="dark"><a rel="6" class="0806" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">6</a></li>
    <li class="dark"><a rel="7" class="0807" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">7</a></li>
    <li class="dark"><a rel="8" class="0808" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">8</a></li>
    <li class="dark"><a rel="9" class="0809" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">9</a></li>
    <li class="dark"><a rel="10" class="0810" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">10</a></li>
    <li class="dark"><a rel="11" class="0811" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">11</a></li>
    <li class="dark"><a rel="12" class="0812" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">12</a></li>
</ul>
```

and I'd like to change color of the current day and another color of the days before.
The class is monthday format.

Comment: How does this have anything to do with password protection?

Comment: Sorry,The question about password is a mistake, the right question is:
I would like to color the day according to today's date, and days before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this

```
// get current date
var today = new Date();
// get days using getDate() and pad to 2 digits
var tdd = zeroPad(today.getDate(),2);
// get months using getMonth() and pad to 2 digits
var tmm = zeroPad(today.getMonth()+1,2);

// get current date
var yesterday = new Date();
// set date to date -1 ie yesterday
yesterday.setDate(today.getDate() - 1);
// get days using getDate() and pad to 2 digits
var ydd = zeroPad(yesterday.getDate(),2);
// get months using getMonth() and pad to 2 digits
var ymm = zeroPad(yesterday.getMonth()+1,2);

// concatenate strings to form class and use css() to set appropriate color
$('.'+tmm + tdd).css('background-color','red');
$('.'+ymm + ydd).css('background-color','blue');
```

Should set the color for today to red and the color for yesterday to blue. Uses the [`Date` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/), [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) and `zeroPad()` function taken from [SO answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2998874/572939)

[Working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/PdYkf/1/)

Answer (score 0):

User the JS:

```
var d = new Date();
alert(d.getDate());
alert(d.getMonth());
```

d.getDate() will display a number between 1 and 31.
g.getMonth() returns the month (from 0-11)

Instead af using 0731 as a class for your , put 0731 as an ID,
and use a ByID getter to update the style class.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

You can help yourself now with these informations.