# Increment 5 digit number in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to output integers with leading zeros in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998784/how-to-output-integers-with-leading-zeros-in-javascript)

I have a function increment, it increments value by 1 on mouse click. But i want it to increment from 00001 to 00002 on mouse click and 00003 etc so on...on each mouse click.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var count = 00001;
    $('#increment').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        count++;
        $('p').text(count);
    });
});
</script>


<p>00001</p>
<input type="button" value="Increment" id="increment"/>
```

Help me please,

Thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var count = 0,
    pad = '00000';
$('#increment').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    count++;
    var ctxt = '' + count;
    $('p').text(pad.substr(0, pad.length - ctxt.length) + ctxt);
});​
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/a8yHN/2/)**