# .text() jquery function removes leading zero from month

Tags: php, jquery, date, concatenation, zero

I am generating a reference number, using `jQuery` and `Php` comprising:
a static string, a dynamic letter of the alphabet,  the date in Month and Year and an autogenerated id.

I have these four elements concatenated as below.

```
$("#refno").text("ABC" + str + <?php echo date('Y') ?>  + <?php echo date('m')?>  + <?php echo $id -> id + 1; ?>);
```

`str` is the dynamic letter , set by selecting from a dropdown.
It is required that I output the month in the `mm` format e.g `09 for September`.

Challenge is, the leading zero in the month is truncated in the resulting ref number. e.g
instead of `ABCR20120923` i get `ABCR2012923` . Yet when I `echo date('m')`  09 is output.

While I could choose to have an `if statement` that concatenates a zero onto the single 
character months, I would want to understand why `zero` is truncated and how I can have it 
displayed.

Thanks.Help Appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

09 on its own in treated like an integer - a number does not make sense with leading zeros.

```
$("#refno").text("ABC" + str + <?php echo date('Y') ?>  + "<?php echo date('m')?>"  + <?php echo $id -> id + 1; ?>);
```

Add quotes

Answer (score 1):

try passing your month as string instead of number

Comment: Thanks, I guess adding double quotes around it will do as below suggests.

Comment: ya sure try adding double quotes around it

Comment: True. "`<?php echo date('m')?>`" did it.

Answer (score 1):

Store your content in a variable and do zero padding(zfill),take a look at this,

[How to output integers with leading zeros in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998784/how-to-output-integers-with-leading-zeros-in-javascript)

Comment: Thanks, true that, integers no make sense with leading zeros. Great now I know about `zfill`.