# How to get complete number with 0 at the front

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, sql, string-formatting

I have number like this:

`0065921922572`

I pass this value as a parameter to a function in the JavaScript.

When i alert the data, it show this:

`65921922572`  (the 00 at the front is removed)

I have tried to convert the number to string, but it still give me the same value.

What should i do to get the number correct?

function in javascript:

```
//function that creates posts
var postHandler = function(postsJSON,ctr) {
    $.each(postsJSON,function(i,post) {
        ctr++;
        var id = 'post-' + post.code;
        //create the HTML
        $('<div></div>')
        .addClass('post')
        .attr('id',id)

        //generate the HTML
        .html(ctr +  ".&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type='checkbox' name='item" + ctr + 
                  "' id='item" + ctr + "' value='" + post.code +"' onClick='countElem("+ ctr +
                  ")'> <input type='hidden' name='tick"+ ctr +"' id='tick"+ ctr +"'>" + post.code + 
                  " -- " + post.description + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type='button' name='del_item' id='del_item'" +
                  " class='but' style='margin-right:100px;' value='x' onclick='delProduct("+ post.code +")'>")

        //inject into the container
        .appendTo($('#posts'))
        .hide()
        .slideDown(250,function() {
            if(i == 0) {
                $.scrollTo($('div#' + id));
            }
        });
    }); 
};
```

function in php:

```
function get_posts($start = 0, $number_of_posts = 300) {
    $posts = array();
    /* get the posts */
    $query = "SELECT distinct(code), description FROM sales_order, outstanding 
                WHERE sales_order.id = outstanding.so_id AND sales_order.outstanding =  'Y'
                AND outstanding.out_status = '' AND sales_order.status 
                NOT IN ('sta_deliver', 'otw_deliver',  'com_deliver', 'cancel') order by description asc LIMIT $start, $number_of_posts";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        //preg_match("/(.*)/",$row['description'],$matches);
        //$row['description'] = strip_tags($matches[1]);
        if($row['code'] != '')
        {
            $strnum = (string)($row['code']);
            $row['code'] = $strnum;
        }
        $posts[] = $row;
    }
    /* return the posts in the JSON format */
    return json_encode($posts);
}
```

Comment: How do you _get_ this number?  Is it provided by a user, retrieved from a javascript function, hard-coded into your page?  Do you know in advance how many zeros it should have or how many digits it should have?

Comment: the information is retrieved from the db..it's barcode, so the number of 0 will be different from 1 data to another data.

Comment: Will each barcode always contain the same number of digits?  If so, you can indeed write a pad function.  If not, you'll need to try to retrieve them as strings.  How is it made accessible to your javascript code?  You don't actually get data from a database using javascript do you?

Comment: i've attached the code above. the data is passed through JSON, and this is how i pass my value the js function: <input type='button' name='del_item' id='del_item' class='but' style='margin-right:100px;' value='x' onclick='delProduct("+ post.code +")'> i did try to convert the value to str by using .toString(), smthg like this delProduct(post.code.toString())

Comment: Will each barcode always contain the same number of digits/characters??  Calling `toString` or concatenating with a string won't work if the var is already a number.

Comment: I'm not asking if the number of zeroes varies.  I'm asking if the number of characters in the final barcode will always be the same.  So, you're saying that your barcodes can have arbitrary length?  If that's the case, then your only solution is to make it so your JSON object contains a string and not a number.

Comment: yeah...i mean the number of chars is not the same. but one thing that i'm wondering, the data type for that data in db is varchar, how come when it's retrieved it becomes number?

Comment: I'm not a JavaScript expert, but I would guess that jQuery might be converting it automatically.  In that case, I don't have a solution off the top of my head.  This is the problem with loosely typed languages! Maybe as a workaround you could prepend a character (like an underscore) to the string before it's converted to JSON and then remove it with your JavaScript.

Comment: How is the JSON created?  Does it come from server-side code like Java?  Do you have the ability to view/modify it?  What does it look like if you view the JSON object in Firebug (or another debugger)?

Comment: i obtain the data from sql as usual, and return the data in JSON format, n when the page is loaded, it will called the function in javascript to display the data.

Comment: What does the `id` attribute look like?  Does it contain zeros?  I've edited the tags in hopes to invite some php experts.

Comment: The right order of solving the problem is by following the chain: database (is the value correct there?) - php (does it fetch properly from database?) - javascript (does it receive the json data properly?).

Comment: yes, it contains 0.just that when i pass this value to the parameter, the function become not working.

Comment: from db until html, everything is correct. it displays the right data. but when it passed to javascript, the data is changed.

Comment: i just get the right data...+_+ i put " around the data, and it works...+_+

Comment: Cool.  Yeah, you should treat strings as strings in the generated html... Glad you fixed it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the feedback as well... ^^

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to output integers with leading zeros in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998784/how-to-output-integers-with-leading-zeros-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Did you check this: http://www.webtoolkit.info/javascript-pad.html
I think the simplest way to deal with padding strings is to create a pad function, simple, clear and not use tricks like slice, arrays and so on.
    You may need a simple and reliable function, not top of art.

Regards,
Radu Cosoveanu

Comment: i couldnt do smthg like that because the number of 0 at the front is vary, since it's a barcode. so, some data will have 0, n some wont have. besides, if got 0, the number of 0 wont always be 2.

Comment: You could if every barcode always contains the same number of digits.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that in your JSON your barcode values are a string not a number.

When JavaScript gets the value as a number it will deem the 0's as not required and subsequently remove them automatically.

As a string: `{ "barcode" : "0065921922572" }`

As a number: `{ "barcode" : 0065921922572 }`

Comment: I believe the JSON is received from an outside source (like server side code), though I could be wrong.

Comment: Yeah but the server side code should probably be able to format it correctly.

Comment: But... does jQuery convert it to a number?

Comment: Why would it, they would have to add a try parseInt to every string in the array, that just doesn't make sense. Values can just be strings.

Comment: I know there are times when jQuery converts `"true"` to `true`, so maybe it does the same with numbers in some cases. I don't know if it does or not (I sure hope it doesn't).

Answer (score 0):

As your code in question is not complete, its hard to say whats really wrong. Would be nice to see code that receives request from server. Witch response its actually gets and does it passes it right to postHandler or alters it.

As if you force "code" to string its gives answer like [{"code":" 00122"}]

And useing $.parseJSON on [{"code":" 00122"}] gives 00122 as string.

But if you want quick batch, you can add a space before code and trim it with javascript.

IN PHP replace:

```
$strnum = (string)($row['code']);
```

to

```
$strnum = " " . $row['code'];
```

and in javascript, after

```
$.each(postsJSON,function(i,post) {
```

add a line

```
post.code = $.trim(post.code);
```