# AngularJS digits in $index

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Say for example I have the following code (pseudo):

```
<div ng-repeat=range>{{ $index }}</div>
```

The result would be

`1 2 3 4 5 6 ...`

How could I go about changing the code above so that the indexes are printed

`001 002 003 004 005 006`? (so that the index is printed as 3 digits)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to output integers with leading zeros in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998784/how-to-output-integers-with-leading-zeros-in-javascript)

Comment: @hexblot The possible duplicate you linked to itself seems itself to have been previously marked as a duplicate of another question...

Comment: @hexblot Creating an AngularJS filter was the big key to answering this question. I don't think this should be considered as a duplicate to the question linked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this pretty easily with a filter.

First, define it like so:

```
myModule.filter("tripleDigit", function() {
  return function(number) {
    if (number !== null && number !== undefined) {
      var str = "" + number;
      while (str.length < 3) str = "0" + str;
      return str;
    }
  };
});
```

Then you can pipe `$index` into it:

```
<div ng-repeat=range>{{ $index | tripleDigit }}</div>
```

Here's an example that defines a filter called `pad` that allows you to pass in how many digits to pad as an argument: http://jsfiddle.net/BinaryMuse/64ycY/

Comment: Nice answer. I was never too sure how to go about implementing filters and the fiddle example has also taught me just how. Thanks!