# Is it possible to return a fixed digit filter?

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible to output a fixed number of digits on a {{ expression }}.

For example say I have timer which is counting down >>> 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, ... 0.

Is it possible to filter this output so that the output is now >>> 10, 09, 08, 07, ... 00.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Well, googling a bit you can find: if (counter < 10) counter = '0' + counter; . do you need anything fancier than that?

Comment: That could work.  Guess there's no built-in formatting options for this?

Comment: What do you mean by "built-in"? Built-in to what?

Comment: You know filters  {{ expression | filter }}.

Comment: Here is another similar discussion with multiple methods using filters:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16880792/angularjs-digits-in-index

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can write your own filter. I took TimSPQR's comment and added to a Jsfiddle with a custom filter.

```
angular.module('MyModule', []).filter('digits', function() {
return function(input) {
   if (input < 10) { 
          input = '0' + input;
      }

      return input;
    }
});
```

Usage in html:

```
Add Leading Zero: {{number|digits}}
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CwUSe/1/)

Keep in mind you will need to add logic to account for non-numbers and numbers that already start with a leading zero. This should give you the basic idea though.

-Cheers

Comment: Thanks that should do the trick!                                     I wasn't sure if this functionality came out-of-the-box.

Comment: Just felt like playing with this one, made it generic so you can have it pad with any number of 0s just by specifying a length after the digit filter as the expression: http://jsfiddle.net/CwUSe/3/

Answer (score 0):

For supporting any length of input it better using the following filter (based on Pointy answer: [Pad a number with leading zeros in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10073699/pad-a-number-with-leading-zeros-in-javascript))

JS:

```
angular.module('MyModule', [])    
.filter('digits', function () {
            return function (input, width, leadingChar) {
                leadingChar = leadingChar || '0';
                input = input + '';
                return input.length >= width ? input : new Array(width - input.length + 1).join(leadingChar) + input;
            }
        });
```

HTML:

```
<span>{{(number | digits : 2}}</span>
```