# Unable to retain leading zeros in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have

```
var x = "0100";

parseInt(x); // returns 100;
```

Is there a way I can retain the leading 0s and yet convert to number in Javascript

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not possible but I have a solution that can help you, is to define a class from where you can get the value as integer and when you call the `toString` method it returns the value with leading zeros

```
function Num ()
{
    this.value = arguments[0];
    this.val = this.valueOf = function () 
    {
       return parseInt(this.value);
    }
    this.toString = function()
    {
       return this.value;
    }
}
```

Now what you can do is to define a new number like this :

```
var x = new Num("00011");
x.val() // returns 11
x.toString() // returns "00011"
```

Answer (score 5):

No.

Numbers don't have leading zeroes; that's a display issue, not a matter of a number's internal representation.

To *display* the number with leading zeroes, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998784/how-to-output-integers-with-leading-zeros-in-javascript).