# Why does console.log exclude my zero from logging?

Tags: javascript

```
class Person {
  constructor(name, address, phone) {
    this.name = name;
    this.address = address;
    this.phone = phone;
  }

  call() {
    console.log(`Calling ${this.phone}...`)
  }
}

const tom = new Person('Tom', 'Uden', 0619616);
tom.call();
```

When calling this, the console only shows "619616". When I add `console.log(tom.phone)` it does log the entire number. Why is the zero excluded when calling a method?

Comment: Because noone is mentioning it: this is non-strict code, and things will get funny, when you remove the nine.

Comment: @ASDFGerte I tried this, never knew my phone number was so interesting. Also, very confused now. Thanks!

Comment: just remember "use strict"; unless you know very well what you are doing. In this case, a leading zero is a legacy notation for octal numbers. Your code would even throw in strict mode. This is just a side note though, the main problem has been described in answers and related comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using it as integer.

If you want to keep zero's, use it as string.

```
class Person {
  constructor(name, address, phone) {
    this.name = name;
    this.address = address;
    this.phone = phone;
  }

  call() {
    console.log(`Calling ${this.phone}...`)
  }
}

const tom = new Person('Tom', 'Uden', '0619616');
tom.call();
```

For explanation, check comments or [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35238742/10473393)

Another good to read reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37004175/10473393 (Thanks for @Amy for sharing in comments)

Comment: Thanks for this solution. Could you also explain why the zeros disappear when using an integer? Has it something to do with JavaScript reading it as 'false' and thus null?

Comment: @tomdevisser No, it just doesn't track leading zeroes because they don't have any mathematical meaning. If you tried to use, say "123.00" as a number, it would remove the trailing zeroes for the same reason. If you want to preserve formatting rather than just the value of the number, you have to make it a string.

Comment: @tomdevisser `01234` is the same number as `1234`.  They have the same, literal representation in binary and are not distinguished.  The only way to distinguish them is to force the leading zeroes to be stored: using a string.

Comment: @tomdevisser I think I should add one caveat to what I said.  In JS (this may apply to other languages), numbers with a leading zero can be considered *octal* by mistake.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37003770/why-javascript-treats-a-number-as-octal-if-it-has-a-leading-zero

Comment: I added Amy's link to the reply, together with another reply that explains basically the same as you guys commented, just to help future Googlers, as a matter of reference.

Comment: @tom If I can add one more thing, while a phone number is a "number", its not the kind of number you're going to use in math.  So, while it's a "number", it's not a "number", if you get my meaning.  It's technically valid to have a phone number with leading zeroes, which need to be retained, and since you aren't going to use math on a phone number, perhaps a string is a more appropriate way to store it.  The same logic applies to zip codes, street numbers, and other "numbers" that are never "math'd".

Comment: @Amy Thanks for adding this, that's a good rule of thumb to keep in mind. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can convert it to string, and pad start the leading zeros. For example, I assume you need a 7 digit phone number.

```
class Person {
  constructor(name, address, phone) {
    this.name = name;
    this.address = address;
    this.phone = phone;
  }

  call() {
    console.log(`Calling ${this.phone.toString().padStart(7, 0)}...`)
  }
}

const tom = new Person('Tom', 'Uden', 0619616);
tom.call();
```

Comment: Thanks for another solution, never heard of padStart. :)

Answer (score 1):

The value what you pass in a `Number` type. If you would like to keep the whole value as is then you need to use `String`, just like the following:

```js
const valueNumber = 0619616;
const valueString = '0619616';

console.log({valueNumber, valueString});
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks! I'm only trying to understand why this is necessary, is there a reason the zero doesn't log?

Comment: @tomdevisser Per my other comment, that leading zero has no representation and cannot be distinguished from the numbers "actual value"

Answer (score 1):

to include zero in left side you should use it as string

```
  constructor(name, address, phone) {
    this.name = name;
    this.address = address;
    this.phone = phone;
  }

  call() {
    console.log(`Calling ${this.phone}...`)
  }
}

const tom = new Person('Tom', 'Uden', '0619616');
tom.call();
```