# Where to place setTimeout for countdown timer

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Working on a countdown timer in React and not understanding how/where to place setTimeout function. It seems to work when I put it in the render before the return, but state properties aren't defined then so it starts counting from zero to negative numbers :/  I have tried doing something like:

```
 class App extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      start: '', //'10:10:10'
      end: '',
      startSec: '', //'36610'
      endSec: ''
    }
    this.clicked = this.clicked.bind(this);
    this.handleTimeout = this.handleTimeout.bind(this);
  }

  handleTimeout() {
    // decrement state.startSec
    //^thought this would trigger re-render every sec when  
    //called in clicked() 

  }

  clicked() {
    let re=/^([0-1]\d|2[0-3]):([0-5]\d):([0-5]\d)$/;
    let validStart = re.test(this.state.start);
    let validEnd = re.test(this.state.end);
    let start = this.state.start.split(":");
    let end = this.state.end.split(":");
    let startSec =  (Number(start[0]) * 3600) + (Number(start[1]) * 60) + (Number(start[2]));
    let endSec = (Number(end[0]) * 3600) + (Number(end[1]) * 60) + (Number(end[2]));


    // validate inputs
    if(!validStart || !validEnd) { alert('please use format HH:MM:SS') }     
    if(endSec > startSec) {
      alert('Please make end time less than start time!');
    }

    //where I am stuck
    this.setState({ startSec: startSec }); 

    if(this.state.startSec > this.state.endSec) {
      setInterval(this.handleTimeout() ,1000);
    }
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2> Timer </h2>
        <div id="timer">
          Start Time <input type="text" placeholder="hh:mm:ss" onChange={(e) => {this.setState({start: e.target.value})}} /><br />
          End Time <input type="text" placeholder="hh:mm:ss" onChange={(e) => {this.setState({end: e.target.value})}}/> <br /><br />
          <button onClick={this.clicked}> Start Countdown </button><br /><br />
          <div id="output">{this.state.startSec}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Updated** https://jsfiddle.net/lydiademi/69z2wepo/91973/

I have referenced posts related to timers like [Countdown timer in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40885923/countdown-timer-in-react)

but wasn't able to connect to this problem,

thanks for any help..!

Comment: Your jsfiddle doesn't seem to be working... By the way, you can add it directly into StackOverflow as a snippet instead

Comment: Please create a working fiddle. Also do not try to `setState` in `componentWillMount` lifecycle hook.

Comment: @NanduKalidindi updated

Answer (score 0):

Well the reason its only calling it once is you need to pass the function into `setInterval`, you are instead calling the function and passing its return value (undefined).

So instead of

```
setInterval(this.handleTimeout() ,1000);
```

It should be

```
setInterval(this.handleTimeout ,1000);
```

- you need to keep track of previously started Intervals so you can stop them before starting a new one

```
if(this.currentInterval) {
  clearInterval(this.currentInterval);
}
this.currentInterval = setInterval(this.handleTimeout, 1000);
```