# How to implement "delayed loader" using apollo-client?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

I want to show the loader only when a certain period of time has elapsed. Apollo does provide a `loading` property but it'd show the loader instantaneously.

I was thinking of hacking something together using `componentWillReceiveProps` but if there's a more idiomatic way of doing this, I'd be more than happy to use that.

Answer (score 1):

For this sort of thing I’d use `componentDidUpdate` and add in a setTimeout or perhaps a React state countdown timer. If it’s only a couple of seconds delay a setTimeout will be fine, but if it’s a long time perhaps state based countdown will be better.

Comment: What is react state countdown timer?

Comment: There used to be an example of one on the React docs but I can’t find it anymore. Here’s one from a SO answer. It may be a little overkill to delay a loading spinner, but you could create a new component in place and pass down props to it and have all this logic in a new component https://stackoverflow.com/q/40885923/1058586

Comment: Grrr. Not a fan of playing with timers. But I'll give it shot! Thanks for the pointer. I'll accept if this works out.