# Add countdown timer to twillio video room

Tags: video, twilio, countdown, duration

I am using twilio-video-app-react I want to add duration to peer to peer video room when it is created and show countdown timer in video room .. after completing that duration I want the video to auto end. I searched everywhere through out the docs but I am not finding any solution .. Is there any way to do this ??

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to write a custom timer ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40885923/countdown-timer-in-react) would help ) in react which starts when your participant/s have joined and once the timer ends you'll need to explicitly call below function to disconnect the call.

```
activeRoom.disconnect();
```

activeRoom is the room object that participant is connected to.