# react-countdown resets when rendered in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating a game which user can tap a button as much as they can in a range of time.

I have use `react-countdown` to create Timer. But when I tap to a button, timer is auto reset.

Here my code.

```
import React, { useState } from "react"
import Countdown from 'react-countdown';

function App() {

  const [name, setName] = useState("")
  const [isLogin, setIsLogin] = useState(false)
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0)

  const submitName = () => {
    setIsLogin(true)
  }

  const updateCounter = () => {
    console.log(counter)
    setCounter(counter + 1)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {!isLogin ? (
        <div>
          <input
            style={{ width: 300, height: 30 }}
            placeholder="Input name here"
            value={name}
            onChange={e => setName(e.target.value)}
          />
          <button
            style={{ width: 50, height: 20, background: "red" }}
            onClick={() => submitName()}
          >Go</button>
        </div>
      ) : (
          <div
            style={{ width: "100vw", height: "100vh", background: "yellow" }}>
            <Countdown date={Date.now() + 100000} />
            <h1>{name}</h1>
            <h3>Click counter: {counter} </h3>
            <button
              style={{
                width: 100,
                height: 50,
                background: "red",
                border: "none",
                borderRadius: 25,
                color: "white",
                cursor: "pointer"
              }}
              onClick={() => updateCounter()}>Click here!</button>
          </div>
        )
      }
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The problem is when I tap the button, `setCounter(counter + 1)` is running and rerender the page. That made the Counter reset.
I know why it have issue but I cannot fix it.

Comment: Obviously, you could create the component, which would handle the clicking and update state locally. Thus, only component with counter will be re-rendered. Check out: https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-zhukovsky-y8w3n?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to memoize the `Countdown` component:

```
const CountdownWrapper = () => <Countdown date={Date.now() + 100000} />;
const MemoCountdown = React.memo(CountdownWrapper);

// usage
<MemoCountdown/>
```

Beforehand, on every render `Date.now()` gets a new value which resets the timer.

[image: Edit Countdown reset]

Comment: Thanks for your support. Another question, how can I use setTimeout instead of react-countdown?

Comment: Its the most searched question in SO and in Google, try looking for it, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40885923/countdown-timer-in-react

Answer (score 1):

```
import React from 'react';

const time = React.useMemo(() => {
    return Date.now() + 120 * 1000;
}, []);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.