# (React)Child component pause its useEffect when the parent re-renders

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-hooks, react-functional-component

Edit: This problem has been solved by adding a second parameter in the useEffect Hooks.

I am new to react and am building a toy react game. I borrowed this timer I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61572623/9537040). If user performs an action and the parent component re-renders, the timer stop counting down for a short period of time. According to (https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html), react will remember the useEffect function, and call it later after performing the DOM updates. If that's the reason, are there any solutions or alternatives to this? If not, can anyone point me in the right direction? Any help will be appreciated!

Here is my code snippet for reference:

```
class Chalkboard extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            minutes: 1,
            seconds: 0,
            addSeconds: 0,
        };
    }

    updateTimer() {
        this.setState({ addSeconds: 0 });
    }

    handleTimer() {
        window.removeEventListener('keydown', this.keyHandling);
        this.setState({
            gameOver: true,
        });
    }

    render() {
       return(
           <Timer
                initialMinutes={this.state.minutes}
                initialSeconds={this.state.seconds}
                onTimer={this.handleTimer}
                addSeconds={this.state.addSeconds}
                updateTimer={this.updateTimer}
            />
           )

}
```

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const Timer = (props) => {
    const { initialMinutes = 0, initialSeconds = 0 } = props;
    const [minutes, setMinutes] = useState(initialMinutes);
    const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState(initialSeconds);

    useEffect(() => {
        let myInterval = setInterval(() => {
            if (seconds > 0) {
                setSeconds(seconds - 1);
            }
            else if (seconds === 0) {
                if (minutes === 0) {
                    clearInterval(myInterval);
                } else {
                    setSeconds(59);
                    setMinutes(minutes - 1);
                }
            }
        }, 1000);
        return () => {
            clearInterval(myInterval);
        };
    });

    useEffect(() =>{
        if(props.addSeconds>0){
            setSeconds(seconds + props.addSeconds);
            props.updateTimer()
        }
        if(minutes === 0 && seconds === 0){
            props.onTimer()
        }
    });


    return (
        <div className = "timer-container" >
            {minutes === 0 && seconds === 0 ? null: (
                <div>
                    {' '}
                    {minutes}:{seconds < 10 ? `0${seconds}` : seconds}
                </div>
            )}
        </div>
    );
};

export default Timer;
```

Comment: are you using useEffect hook in a class component?

Comment: can you show us a bit more code ?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean when you said `timer stop counting down`. Does this resets and start from the beginning and or just pause for a period and then continue from there.? More code will help

Comment: Sorry, I've updated my question.

Comment: Yea, the timer paused for a period, and then continue from there. And if I keep clicking a button that causes the parent to re-render, the timer will pause forever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you provide an example on https://codesandbox.io/?

Try to pass `[props, minutes, seconds]` as a second parameter in useEffect hook.
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#conditionally-firing-an-effect

Comment: Adding [props.addSeconds,minutes, seconds] as a second parameter in the useEffect hook solved my problem! Thank you so much.

Comment: @CharlotteCheng if your problem is solved, mark the answer and upvote it so others can take benefit as well.