# How to make a simple count down timer from milliseconds with Javascript/REACT

Tags: javascript, reactjs, timer, setinterval

I'm wondering the best way to make a simple minute/second countdown timer to next refresh. This component's prop get updated every 5 minutes and counts down until the next refresh per second. This seems to get out of sync pretty quickly. Any thoughts?

I'm not sure if `timeRemaining < 0` makes sense -- if we subtract 1000 from 1100 we would have 100 (how do I account for that?) I'm hoping there's a better way. Should I convert this back to seconds?

Thanks for any feedback.

```
...

const CountdownToNextRefresh = ({milliToNextRounded5Min}) => {
  const [, setCount] = useState(0);
  const [timeRemaining, setTimeRemaining] = useState(milliToNextRounded5Min);

  useEffect(() => {
    const oneSecond = 1000;
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setCount((prevCount) => prevCount + 1);
      setTimeRemaining(timeRemaining < 0 ? milliToNextRounded5Min : timeRemaining - oneSecond);
    }, oneSecond);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, [timeRemaining, milliToNextRounded5Min]);

  function msToTime(milliseconds) {
    // Get hours from milliseconds.
    const hoursFromMilli = milliseconds / (1000*60*60);
    const absoluteHours = Math.floor(hoursFromMilli);
    const h = absoluteHours > 9 ? absoluteHours : `0${absoluteHours}`;

    // Get remainder from hours and convert to minutes.
    const minutesfromHours = (hoursFromMilli - absoluteHours) * 60;
    const absoluteMinutes = Math.floor(minutesfromHours);
    const m = absoluteMinutes > 9 ? absoluteMinutes : `0${absoluteMinutes}`;

    // Get remainder from minutes and convert to seconds.
    const seconds = (minutesfromHours - absoluteMinutes) * 60;
    const absoluteSeconds = Math.floor(seconds);
    const s = absoluteSeconds > 9 ? absoluteSeconds : `0${absoluteSeconds}`;

    return h === "00" ? `${m}:${s}` : `${h}:${m}:${s}`;
  }

return (<div>{msToTime(timeRemaining)}</div>)
}
```

Comment: This may help [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40885923/countdown-timer-in-react)

Comment: @raaahad -- Maybe my question is more, "The best way to use milliseconds for an accurate count down".