# How to stop useState hook setState re-render in the useEffect? I am trying to code a count down function and the mins can sync from another component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to code a countdown clock and the "mins" is from a brother component.
If I take off `setMin` from `useEffect` then it is not changing while the value change in source components, but if I leave it in `useEffect` it will re-rendering every time if the seconds change and makes it immutable. Anyway, can I fix this problem?
If I need `useRef` how can I use it with `setMin`?

```
export default function Timer(props) {
  const { count } = props;
  const [isPlay, setIsPlay] = useState(false);
  const [isRestore, setIsRestore] = useState(false);
  const [second, setSecond] = useState(0);
  const [isBreak, setIsBreak] = useState(false);
  const [min, setMin] = useState(count)

  useEffect(() => {
    setMin(count)
    let alarm = document.getElementById("beep");
    const countdown = () => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        if (second === 0 && min > 0) {
          setMin(min-1);
          setSecond(59);
        } else if (min >= 0 && second > 0) {
          setSecond(second - 1);
        } else {
          alarm.play();
          alarm.addEventListener("ended", () => {
            setIsBreak(!isBreak);
          });
        }
      }, 1000);
    };
    if (isPlay) {
      countdown();
    } else {
      alarm.pause();
    }

    if (isRestore) {
      setIsPlay(false);
      alarm.currentTime = 0;
      setIsRestore(false);
    }
  },[isPlay, isRestore, second, isBreak,min,count]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the majority of your logic should be outside of the useEffect hook. Take a look at this answer [Countdown timer in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40885923/countdown-timer-in-react), it accomplishes pretty much the same task as yours and should help you get an idea of the necessary logic

Comment: Hi Nathan, Thank you for your quick response. I moved my logic outside of the useEffect Hook, but the minutes still not changing if I increment the count from another component. if I log count in console it is increment as normal but ```const [min, setMin] = useState(count)``` not change the min value unless I put ```setMin(count)``` inside useEffect but I will over-write the minutes of countdown function