# Time filter doesn't work for time above 60 but below 70 seconds

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework, filter

So I have a custom filter to display seconds (85) into clock display (1:25) but it doesn't work for certain times. Specifically above 60 seconds but below 70 seconds, it displays like this: 1:7 (67 secs) or 1:0 (60 secs). I don't know where to add to the logic to fix it.

Thanks for the help in advance :)

.

```
filter('timeconvert', function() {

  // Create the return function
  // set the required parameter name to **number**
  return function(number) {

// Ensure that the passed in data is a number
if(isNaN(number)) {

  // If the data is not a number
  return number;

} else {

  // If the data we are applying the filter to is a number, perform the actions to check it's ordinal suffix and apply it.
  var hrs=0;
  var min=0;
  var sec=0;

  if (number/3600>=1){
    var hrs=Math.floor(number/3600);
    var min=Math.floor((number-(hrs*3600))/60);
    var sec=(number-(hrs*3600)-(min*60));
    return hrs+':'+min +':'+ sec;
  }      
  else if (number/60>=1){
    var min=Math.floor(number/60);
    var sec=Math.floor(number-(min*60));
    return min +':'+ sec;
  }
  else if(number/60<1&&number/10>=1){
    var min=0;
    var sec=number;
    return min +':'+ sec;
  }
  else if(number/10<1){
    var min=0;
    var sec=number;
    return min +':'+ '0'+sec;
  }
}
  }
```

Comment: So zero pad the number

Comment: Can you add input values you are passing to filter function?

Comment: What is the desired output?  1:7 *is* 67 seconds because it's 1 minute and 7 seconds.

Comment: The desired output would be 1:07

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to output integers with leading zeros in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998784/how-to-output-integers-with-leading-zeros-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, just changed the middle portion to look at the remainder and the added a zero...Thanks for the help anyway

```
     else if (number/60>=1&&number%60>10){
        var min=Math.floor(number/60);
        var sec=Math.floor(number-(min*60));
        return min +':'+ sec;
      }
      else if (number/60>=1&&number%60<10){
        var min=Math.floor(number/60);
        var sec=Math.floor(number-(min*60));
        return min +':0'+ sec;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your code gets the right values for minutes and all it needs to do is add a 0 to the string, I'd suggest removing your return statements from each else block and then handling the logic to return the string once those value have been set.

```
 return hrs + ':' + (min < 10 ? '0' + min.toString() : min) + sec;
```

Comment: That is not bad but I don't want it to display the hrs for certain numbers, so I would prefer to handle in separately instead of getting 0:56:07, I like 56:07.

Comment: You can use the same logic for hours with the ternary operator as well, would return 56:7 if you used this for 0:56:07.  (because I haven't padded the seconds, but same logic applies as from minutes)

      return ( hrs > 0 ? hrs + ':'  : '')  + (min < 10 ? '0' + min.toString() : min) + sec;