# Why is this <input type="range> slider skipping the first 10 of 100 items?

Tags: javascript, html

**Here is my JS:**

```js
document.querySelector('input[type=range]').addEventListener('input', function(event) {
  console.log(event.target.value);
  console.log(window.location);

  document.querySelector('#day0' + event.target.value).scrollIntoView({
    behavior: 'smooth'
  });
});
```

```html
<input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="7" step="1">
```

There are 100 items (labelled in #day000 format from #day001 to #day100). The slider will skip the first ten days when I slide to the right and when I slide all the way back to the left it will stop at day #009 or #010.

I'd like it to scroll all the way to the beginning. Any ideas?

Comment: Your snippet generates errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're not adding all the needed zeroes. When the slider value is `7`, the selector will be `#day07`, not `#day007`.

It also won't work when the slider reaches the far right, because the selector will be `#day0100` instead of `#day100`.

See [How to output integers with leading zeros in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998784/how-to-output-integers-with-leading-zeros-in-javascript) for how to pad a number with leading zeroes. Then you can use:

```
document.querySelector('#day' + pad(event.target.value, 3)).scrollIntoView({
    behavior: 'smooth'
});
```

or you could change your IDs to `day0` through `day100` instead of `day000` throough `day100`.

Comment: I like using this style of padding numbers for javascript: `'#day' + ("000" + event.target.value).slice(-3)`.

Comment: @JosephMarikle That's in one of the answers to the question I linked to.

Comment: Yep, I know.  I just wanted to highlight it.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7254108/854246) uses that method (albeit with scientific notification), but even that one stuffs the code into a helper function, which OP may not need.  Either way, the important part is the logic error of using `#day01` for a selector, which you pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

I see you have added a `value` property of 7 to your input, drop that or set it to zero and I think you're good to go