# Get JSON parameters

Tags: javascript, angular, model

I need to get the values ​​of the parameters of a JSON model I have.

My output returns:

```
console.log(this.model);
```

> { year:2017, month:08, day:05}

I need to get the values and create a object for example `date='2017-08-05'`.

Comment: That format that you put the json makes no sense, there's no way to a json return a object like `{ year=2017 }`. It is a string? Like `{ "year=2017" }`? Or maybe the output returns `{ year : 2017 }`?

Comment: sorry, you have a reason, my json   { year:2017, month:08, day:05}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what you need to do with it, you could use a JavaScript template literal: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

```
myNewObject.date = `${this.model.year}-${this.model.month}-${this.model.day}`;
```

If the date values are really numbers and not strings, then you may need to "0" pad them. There is an example for this here: [How to output integers with leading zeros in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998784/how-to-output-integers-with-leading-zeros-in-javascript)

Comment: Its will return `2017-8-5` I hope that it does not need to have the 0 before, like `2017-08-05`

Comment: That is, date = '2017-08-05' and go inside object = {date: '2017-08-05', name: "lenin", token : "5646d54adad"} but the object to which I send I am shown this object = {0: "2", 1: "0",3:"1",4:"7",name: "lenin", token :"5646d54adad"}