# How to convert a number, as is, to string

Tags: javascript, string

This is a strange one but I need to convert a number to string; a number with zero in front.

```
3.toString()
String(3)
3 + ""
```

All those would convert to string, but what about `03`? I need `03` to become `"03"`. How to achieve this? Doing the above with `03`, I get `"3"`. basically, I am doing queries by date where the value can be `"03/15/2017"`

From an input's value, I need to convert that exactly to string without dropping the `0` if present.

Here's my example:

```
<input type="text" value=03 /> // val
dateString = "03/15/2017"
dateString.indexOf(val) !== -1
```

Comment: If you put `03` in a variable, it'll just be `3`.

Comment: @LoremIpsum Correct, just dont know how to word it.

Comment: Your input is already a string

Comment: Where is your `03` coming from? If it's being input, it's probably already a string.

Comment: Use a `date` or `text` input instead of `number`? That lets the user write `03` which will get transmitted to your server as `03`

Comment: If it's an input element the value would already be a string. Just prepend a zero if its length is 1.

Comment: When I console log, from a text input, I dont see the quotes around 03

Comment: Convert the number to a string, and if the string is too short prepend a "0".

Comment: @Pointy Hmmmm....never thought of that way.

Comment: @Sylar the console does not show quote characters around strings.

Comment: If the input is `03/15/2017` just split on the slash: `'03/15/2017'.split('/')`. `03` will be the first element.

Comment: Simple way is `('0'+num).slice(-2)`

Comment: @Andy I may not be explaining correctly. The user types `03` and Im using `===` to match the date.

Comment: You should probably add the code to your question. You might be better off with a dropdown. That way you can control the input, rather than fix what the user has entered.

Comment: @Andy Sure, Ive made the edit

Comment: [Your code works](https://jsfiddle.net/a5rzxokd/). It checks the value against the string. In the example `indexOf` returns `0` because it's in the string. You don't need to convert anything if you're sure the user enters `03`. It's already a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are confusing strings and numbers. Numbers have a "canonical form" that you see, for example, when you print or log them; however, numbers can have many different formats that all get parsed or converted into the same number.

For example, consider the following number literals which all represent the same number (3):

```
[3, 3.0, 03, +3e0].map(Number); // => [3, 3, 3, 3]
```

Moreover, parsing those literals from string values also results in the same number:

```
['3', '3.0', '03', '+3e0'].map(Number); // => [3, 3, 3, 3]
```

What this means is that if you want a number to appear differently than its canonical form then you must "format" it. In your example, it sounds like you're already getting a formatted number (`"03"`) so perhaps you just want to validate the string to confirm that it is an acceptable number and use the input string as-is, or a formatted version of the validated number. For example:

```
function validateNumber(s) {
  // Parse the input string as a number.
  var n = Number(s);
  // Validate the number to make sure it's ok based on your business logic.
  if (!Number.isInteger(n)) {
    throw new Error('invalid integer: ' + s);
  }
  // Format it to look like we want.
  var formatted = String(s);
  return ((formatted.length < 2) ? '0' : '') + formatted;
}
validateNumber(3); // => "03"
validateNumber("03"); // => "03"
validateNumber(20); // => "20"
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out there's an inbuilt to do this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart

```
console.log("3".padStart(2, "0"));
```

Comment: But also have to note browser support . None in IE

Comment: @charlietfl True that. There's a polyfil on the man page that should help.

Comment: Good catch though...never knew it existed

Answer (score 0):

You have a function for return 03 if you use 3, I get this function from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998784/how-to-output-integers-with-leading-zeros-in-javascript)

```
console.log(pad(3,2))
function pad(num, size) {
    var s = num+"";
    while (s.length < size) s = "0" + s;
    return s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    function appendZero(val){
        val = val.toString();
        return val.length == 1 ? "0"+val : val

    }

    appendZero(3) // '03'
```

Comment: In your return line, there's no need to use `.toString()`, it's already a string.

Comment: Yes,but just a check incase the value passed in is a number.If the datatype of  value passed is a number then the result returned will be '3' instead of '03'.Hence inorder to handle that,I thought of stringifying it :)

Comment: I meant `val` is already a `string` so it should be `return val.length == 1 ? "0"+val : val` .

Comment: Yeah correct.Thanks for pointing out that.Now I understand :)

Answer (score 0):

you can get with an `if` condition to check if the number is less than 10.
`function addZero(n) {`
    `return (n < 10) ? ("0" + n) : n.toString();`
`}`
`console.log(addZero(7))`

Answer (score 0):

Considering your example this may work for you:

```
var val = 3;
dateString = "03/15/2017";
var indexOfVal = dateString.indexOf(val.toString().padStart(2,'0'));
console.log(indexOfVal); // 0

//Another approach could be
var datePartsArray = dateString.split("/");
var month = datePartsArray[0]; //"03"
var day = datePartsArray[1]; //"15"
var year = datePartsArray[2]; //"2017"

if(month===val.toString().padStart(2,'0')){
   console.log(true);}
else{
    console.log(false);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is also a short one I usually use for concatenating date-strings:

```js
mydate=3;
mystring = ("0"+3).slice(-2);
console.log(mystring);
```

Answer (score -3):

Maybe this helps:

```
var today = new Date();
var d = today.getDate();
var m = today.getMonth() + 1;
var y = today.getFullYear();
var shortDate = m.toString().padStart(2,'0') + '/' + 
d.toString().padStart(2,'0') + '/' + y.toString();
console.log(shortDate);
```

In the third line I add 1 to today.getMonth() because JavaScript counts months from 0 to 11 in a year.

You can find more about JavaScript Date Methods [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_methods.asp)

Comment: Thanks for your observation @charlietfl, It made me read the question again so I could come up with a -maybe- helpful answer.