# Is there a way to get a "distance" formatted as "HH:mm:ss" in date-fns?

Tags: javascript, date-fns

I want to show a timer in the format `HH:mm:ss`, where that is a "countdown" to some target time. My first thought was to use [`intervalToDuration`](https://date-fns.org/v2.29.3/docs/intervalToDuration) because of its description:

> An object that combines two dates to represent the time interval.

```
function getTimeUntilEventStart(eventTime: Date, timeZone: string) {
  return intervalToDuration({
    start: utcToZonedTime(new Date(), timeZone),
    end: eventTime,
  });
}
```

However, when I have it as a duration, there doesn't seem to be any formatting options other than `formatDistance` and `formatDistanceToNow`, which format it in the form `1 hour from now`

Is there a way to get the distance from now in an arbitrary user-defined format?

Comment: This might help: [Format a duration from seconds using date-fns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48776140/format-a-duration-from-seconds-using-date-fns)

Comment: It seems like you might want the relative time format method from Intl? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/RelativeTimeFormat