# Generate Reference Number to Google Sheets automatically using Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to generate a reference number every time a new data in inserted automatically from Google Form.
I would like to generate the format as TMS180001 until the maximum possible reference number which is TMS189999. I could not figure how to format the value/string to 0001 instead of 1 and when I ran below code nothing happened.

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
var Time = e.values [0]; //column 1 timestamp
var TMSrefnum = [10]; //column 1 till 9 are other information while 
                      //column 10 is the reference number

if (Time = true); //if timestamp has value then add reference
                  //number to column 11
var i = 1 ; i < 9999 ; i++;
TMSrefnum = "TMS18" + toString(i);
}
```

Comment: I guess you are missing a `for(...)` ... and much more

Comment: Oh yeah I forgot to input the for statement but it still did not work. for (i = 1 ; i < 1000 ; i++);

Comment: I've answered your specific question, but there are several other issues with your code. Is this script meant to write just the reference number or all of the form data?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I pad a value with leading zeros?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267283/how-can-i-pad-a-value-with-leading-zeros)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Zero Padding

For **zero padding** use your own functions e.g.

```js
Number.prototype.pad = function(size) {
    var s = String(this);
    while (s.length < (size || 2)) {s = "0" + s;}
    return s;
}


(9).pad();  //returns "09"

(7).pad(3);  //returns "007"
```

This will allow you to execute the `.pad()` method on any `Number` in your script.

---

Or write a method that looks something like this:

```
function pad(num, size) {
    var s = "000000000" + num;
    return s.substr(s.length-size);
}


pad(98);   // returns "000000098"
```

---

#### Sources:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/11187738/1139105
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/2998822/1139105

Answer (score 0):

See this answer to the question [How to output integers with leading zeros in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998784/how-to-output-integers-with-leading-zeros-in-javascript).

You'll need to create an extra function outside the `onFormSubmit()` function (or include the [Polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart)).

```
function pad(num, size) {
  var s = num+"";
  while (s.length < size) s = "0" + s;
  return s;
}
```

Then you would call

```
TMSrefnum = "TMS18" + pad(currentEntryNumber, 4);
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to produce the reference number from below code.

```
var sheet1 = ss.getSheets()[0];

function pad(num, size) {
var s = num + "";
while (s.length < size) s = "0" + s;
return s;
}  

var valuerange = sheet1.getRange("A1:A").getValues();
var lastrownumber = valuerange.filter(String).length-1;
var TMSNUM = "TMS18" + pad(lastrownumber, 4);
```