# How to add numbers with 0s in front in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

(This is not a duplicate. I can't find the solution in the link provided).

Say I have an input from a user in an html form intended as a serial number or some such. This number can start with 0s. Example, 0001.

In Javascript, if that number (0001) is incremented, it becomes 2.

I would like to preserve the leading 0s to get 0002.

How do I do that in Javasript?

Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: Probably duplicate of:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998784/how-to-output-integers-with-leading-zeros-in-javascript

Comment: A simple web search should have answered this for you. Basic research is expected here before asking questions

Answer (score 1):

Use [padStart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart) to pad the start of a number. However numbers don't start with zero so the number will have to be displayed as a string.

To find the number of zeros, you can do:

```
('001'.match(/^0+/) || [''])[0].length
```

- **`'001'.match(/^0+/)`** – matches as many zeros as possible from the start of the string
- **`|| ['']`** – if the match returns `undefined`, use an array with an empty string (aka a fallback value)
- **`[0]`** – get the first value in the returned array (either the match or the fallback)
- **`.length`** – get the length of the string

```js
let nums = [
  '1',
  '01',
  '001',
  '0001'
]

let str = ''

for (let i of nums) {
  let numZeros = (i.match(/^0+/) || [''])[0].length
  let num = Number(i)
  while (num < 20) {
    str += `<p>${String(num++).padStart(numZeros + 1, '0')}</p>`
  }
}

document.body.innerHTML = str
```

Comment: The number of leading 0's is unknown. The input could be 01 or 001 or 0001 or 00001. When added, I would like the result to be 02, 002, 0002 and 00002 respectively.

Comment: `.split('')` is unneccessary.