# How can I loop 2D array and modify its values

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursive-datastructures

Given 2D array of photos taken while `John doe` was on trips so I'm asked to rename pictures and replace `actual` name with `city name` where a picture was taken.

```
const photos = [
['photo.jpg', 'kigali','2013-09-05 14:08:09'],
['demmpa.jpg', 'kigali','2013-09-05 14:08:09'],
['third.jpg', 'kibuye','2013-02-05 12:08:09']
['forthpic.jpg', 'kampala','2013-02-05 12:08:09']
]
   photos.map((photo, index)=>{
    photo.filter((photo, index)=> console.log(photo))
    
  })
```

Actual output

```
"photo.jpg"
"kigali"
"2013-09-05 14:08:09"
"demmpa.jpg"
"kigali"
"2013-09-05 14:08:09"
```

Expected output

```
kigali01.jpg
kigali02.jpg
Kibuye1.jpg
kampala1.jpg
```

Comment: What have you tried. Please give atleast 2 elements in your expected input so we can help you

Comment: why the numbering on kigal are with `0` and the others it's without?

Comment: the first appearing `city`  to begin with `0` then increment the number in the same city

Comment: Are you sure it shouldn't return either `['kigali01.jpg', 'kigali02.jpg', 'Kibuye01.jpg', 'kampala01.jpg']` or  `['kigali1.jpg', 'kigali2.jpg', 'Kibuye1.jpg', 'kampala1.jpg']`?  The changing style of the numbers if very odd.  But also, where's your own attempt?  Have you tried to solve this?  What issues did you have?   Please see [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Comment: `0` has to be appended on the first city only and the similar photo taken in the same city @ScottSauyet

Comment: I think you really need to give another example or two.  Also, please show your own attempts.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `map`. And the `occurrence` will just keep the number of how many times the name is repeated.

**Note:** if you need to add leading zeros, Please check it out
[How to output numbers with leading zeros in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998784/how-to-output-numbers-with-leading-zeros-in-javascript)

```js
const photos = [
  ['photo.jpg', 'kigali','2013-09-05 14:08:09'],
  ['demmpa.jpg', 'kigali','2013-09-05 14:08:09'],
  ['third.jpg', 'kibuye','2013-02-05 12:08:09'],
  ['forthpic.jpg', 'kampala','2013-02-05 12:08:09']
];

const occurrence = {}

const newArray = photos.map(arr => {

  const ext = arr[0].split('.')[1]; // file extension

  if (occurrence[arr[1]]) { // check whether the name is already there
    occurrence[arr[1]]++;
    return `${arr[1]}${occurrence[arr[1]]}.${ext}`;
  }
  
  occurrence[arr[1]] = 1;
  return `${arr[1]}1.${ext}`;

});


console.log(newArray)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let photos = [
['photo.jpg', 'kigali','2013-09-05 14:08:09'],
['demmpa.jpg', 'kigali','2013-09-05 14:08:09'],
['third.jpg', 'kibuye','2013-02-05 12:08:09'],
['forthpic.jpg', 'kampala','2013-02-05 12:08:09']
]

 photos = Array.from(photos).map((photo)=>{
 const format = photo[0].split('.')[1]
 photo[0]=photo[1]+'.'+format
 return photo
})
```

Comment: Can you please explain your code? How does it produce the expected output?

Comment: first i did a mapping on the photos array next i took the format from the index one then i altred the first index to the city name + the format

Comment: The replicated name should have numbers. I think that missing in your code.