# Show timer in 2 digits instead of one react-timer-hook

Tags: reactjs, timer, react-hooks

I'm using [react-timer-hook](https://amrlabib.github.io/react-timer-hook/) in my react application. It's working great but in the example the timer has two digits for hours, minutes and seconds but when I import it and use the timer as a component in my app, the stop watch is showing one digit and only gets to two digits when the value increase above 9. Can anyone assist me in adding a trailing zero if the time is less than 10?

This is the screenshot from the react timer hook.

[image]

And this is the screenshot when I'm using it.

[image]

Below is the code how I'm using it.

```
import React from "react"; 
import { useStopwatch } from "react-timer-hook"; 
export default function MyStopwatch() {    
const {seconds, minutes,hours, days, isRunning, start, pause, reset } =
useStopwatch({ autoStart: true });};   
return (
<>
<div>
<span>{hours}</span>:<span>{minutes}</span>:<span>{seconds}</span>
</div>
</>   
); 
}
```

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998784/how-to-output-numbers-with-leading-zeros-in-javascript

Comment: Hi @drodil thanks for the link i think this could solve my problem but im using an external library and im new to react can you tell me how can i add this pad function to my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well this is one option:

```
import React from "react"; 
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { useStopwatch } from "react-timer-hook"; 
export default function MyStopwatch() {    
  const {
    seconds,
    minutes,
    hours,
    days,
    isRunning,
    start,
    pause,
    reset,
  } = useStopwatch({ autoStart: true });

  const formatTime = (time) => {
    return String(time).padStart(2, '0')
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <span>{formatTime(hours)}</span>:<span>{formatTime(minutes)}</span>:<span>{formatTime(seconds)}</span>
    </div>
  ); 
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <MyStopwatch />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Playground version here https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-byo61?file=/index.js