# Unusual behavior when value of variable change (easy)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-router

Happy 2k22! I am building a countdown timer. I have two files. The first file takes the countDown time from `input` and the second from `select dropdown` .

I have implemented an `increment` button in the first file. It increases the countDown time by `inc` seconds i.e. `time = time + inc`.

##### So what's peculiar?

Thing is that when `inc` is replaced with any constant value, it works properly.

```
<button onClick={() => setSecondsRemaining(secondsRemaining + 3)}>
      Increment {inc} sec
</button>
```

But when I used the input to enter the value and supply it through the variable `inc`, then it does not work. It increases randomly.

```
<button onClick={() => setSecondsRemaining(secondsRemaining + inc)}>
      Increment {inc} sec
</button>
```

##### **You can visit `InputCountDown.js`  [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/check-clock-phase1-wwdy9?file=/src/InputCountDown.js:2535-2659)**

This is the full code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const STATUS = {
  STARTED: "Started",
  STOPPED: "Stopped"
};

export default function InputCountDown() {
  const [time, setTime] = useState(0);
  const [inc, setInc] = useState(0);

  const handleOnChange = (e) => {
    //console.log(e.target.value);
    setTime(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleOnChangeIncrement = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.value);
    setInc(e.target.value);
  };

  const [secondsRemaining, setSecondsRemaining] = useState(time * 60);

  //console.log(time);

  const [status, setStatus] = useState(STATUS.STOPPED);

  const secondsToDisplay = secondsRemaining % 60;
  const minutesRemaining = (secondsRemaining - secondsToDisplay) / 60;
  const minutesToDisplay = minutesRemaining % 60;
  const hoursToDisplay = (minutesRemaining - minutesToDisplay) / 60;

  const handleStart = () => {
    setStatus(STATUS.STARTED);
    setSecondsRemaining(time * 60);
  };
  const handleStop = () => {
    setStatus(STATUS.STOPPED);
  };
  const handleReset = () => {
    setStatus(STATUS.STOPPED);
    setSecondsRemaining(time * 60);
  };
  useInterval(
    () => {
      if (secondsRemaining > 0) {
        setSecondsRemaining(secondsRemaining - 1);
      } else {
        setStatus(STATUS.STOPPED);
      }
    },
    status === STATUS.STARTED ? 1000 : null
    // passing null stops the interval
  );
  return (
    <>
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Countdown Using Input</h1>
        <div style={{ padding: "12px" }}>
          <label htmlFor="time"> Enter time in minutes </label>
          <input
            type="text"
            id="time"
            name="time"
            value={time}
            onChange={(e) => handleOnChange(e)}
          />
        </div>
        <div style={{ padding: "12px" }}>
          <label htmlFor="inc"> Enter increment </label>
          <input
            type="text"
            id="inc"
            name="inc"
            value={inc}
            onChange={(e) => handleOnChangeIncrement(e)}
          />
        </div>

        <button onClick={handleStart} type="button">
          Start
        </button>
        <button onClick={handleStop} type="button">
          Stop
        </button>
        <button onClick={handleReset} type="button">
          Reset
        </button>
        <div style={{ padding: 20, fontSize: "40px" }}>
          {twoDigits(hoursToDisplay)}:{twoDigits(minutesToDisplay)}:
          {twoDigits(secondsToDisplay)}
          <div>
            <button onClick={() => setSecondsRemaining(secondsRemaining + inc)}>
              Increment {inc} sec
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>Status: {status}</div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

// source: https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/
function useInterval(callback, delay) {
  const savedCallback = useRef();

  // Remember the latest callback.
  useEffect(() => {
    savedCallback.current = callback;
  }, [callback]);

  // Set up the interval.
  useEffect(() => {
    function tick() {
      savedCallback.current();
    }
    if (delay !== null) {
      let id = setInterval(tick, delay);
      return () => clearInterval(id);
    }
  }, [delay]);
}

// https://stackoverflow.com/a/2998874/1673761
const twoDigits = (num) => String(num).padStart(2, "0");
```

**You can visit `InputCountDown.js`  [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/check-clock-phase1-wwdy9?file=/src/InputCountDown.js:2535-2659)**

Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

It's a very basic rule you missed mate. Whenever you get anything from TextInput, its always a string, even if you entered an integer. Try this:

```
<button onClick={() => setSecondsRemaining(secondsRemaining + parseInt(inc))}>
      Increment {inc} sec
</button>
```

Comment: Yeah, and `300 + "5"` does not result in `305` but in `"3005"`. Alternatively to `parseInt` you can also just use the [unary `+` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unary_plus) `secondsRemaining + +inc`

Answer (score 1):

When consuming values from input elements recall that these are always string type values. Best to maintain the number type state invariant, so do the conversion from string to number when updating state.

```
const handleOnChange = (e) => {
  setTime(Number(e.target.value));
};

const handleOnChangeIncrement = (e) => {
  setInc(Number(e.target.value));
};
```

To help ensure users are entering number-like data into the inputs, specify each input to be `type="number"`.

```
<div style={{ padding: "12px" }}>
  <label htmlFor="time"> Enter time in minutes </label>
  <input
    type="number" // <-- number type
    id="time"
    name="time"
    value={time}
    onChange={handleOnChange}
  />
</div>
<div style={{ padding: "12px" }}>
  <label htmlFor="inc"> Enter increment </label>
  <input
    type="number" // <-- number type
    id="inc"
    name="inc"
    value={inc}
    onChange={handleOnChangeIncrement}
  />
</div>
```

Recall also that when enqueueing state updates that if the next state value *depends* on the previous state value, i.e. when incrementing counts, etc..., that you should use a functional state update.

```
<button onClick={() => setSecondsRemaining(time => time + inc)}>
  Increment {inc} sec
</button>
```

[image: Edit unusual-behavior-when-value-of-variable-change-easy]