# Javascript, what does the 1 in slice(1) refer to in this program?

Tags: javascript

In this program, I understand (I think) that paragraph.charAT(0) = "%" checks whether the first character in paragraph is equal to %, i.e. the counting starts at 0, so charAT(0) is the first character

However, in the line, paragraph.slice(1), what does the 1 refer to? Is it slicing off the first character?, which in this case will be at 0 position?

```
function processParagraph(paragraph) {
  var header = 0;
  while (paragraph.charAt(0) == "%") {
    paragraph = paragraph.slice(1);
    header++;
  }

  return {type: (header == 0 ? "p" : "h" + header),
          content: paragraph};
}

show(processParagraph(paragraphs[0]));
```

Comment: see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice). MDC is a great resource for javascript.

Comment: See also [What is the difference between String.slice and String.substring in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2243824/what-is-the-difference-between-string-slice-and-string-substring-in-javascript)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It extracts a substring starting at index 1 (2nd character) of the paragraph string.

For example, consider this:

```
var paragraph = "Hi my name is Russell";
console.log( paragraph.slice(1) ); //returns 'i my name is Russell'
```

Comment: thank you @Russell Dias, so if paragraph string started "%aaaaa", after slice(1), paragraph string would start "aaaaa"?

Comment: @mjm, to elaborate, your code as a whole slices off any number of percent signs from the start of the paragraph, when you take the loop into consideration.

Answer (score 3):

> [**`.slice`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice)
>
> ```
> string.slice(beginslice[, endSlice])
> ```
>
> Extracts a section of a string and returns a new string.

It returns everything *after the first character*, essentially cutting the first character off.

Answer (score 1):

It removes the first character from the string and returns that without altering the original string. I recommend you look at the [documentation for `slice`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113139/javascript-what-does-the-1-in-slice1-refer-to-in-this-program).

Answer (score 1):

it's slicing off the first character (which is a "%")