# How can I cut the 1st char from a string in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Does anyone know how can I cut the 1st char from the string in jquery?

Example:
If I have string as following:

```
var test = '3265';
```

How can I cut only the 1st char so that the output will be '3' instead?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Why jQuery?? Just use plain old javascript:

```
var first = test.substring(0, 1)
```

Answer (score 3):

No need for jQuery, straight javascript:

```
var test = '3265'
var first = test.slice(0,1);
```

Some thoughts on the differences between .substring(), .substr() and .slice() : http://rapd.wordpress.com/2007/07/12/javascript-substr-vs-substring/

also:  [What is the difference between String.slice and String.substring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2243824/what-is-the-difference-between-string-slice-and-string-substring-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

```
Array.prototype.shift.apply(test);
```