# Capitalize first letter in java script

Tags: javascript, capitalize

I know this has been answered before, but I'm a newb and I can't get it to work in my situation.  Basically, I have pages that call the URL and display part of them on the page.  I am hoping to have the first letter of the displayed word capitalize automatically.

This is an example of what i'm using:

```
<script>
var str = (window.location.pathname);
var str2 = "/seedling/";
document.write(str.substr(str2.length,(str.length - str2.length - 1 ) ) );
</script>
```

Thanks so much for your help, it is much appreciated!!

Comment: Answered [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026069/capitalize-the-first-letter-of-string-in-javascript).

Comment: Just for your own knowledge, this is called `Proper Case`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Capitalize the first letter of string in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026069/capitalize-the-first-letter-of-string-in-javascript)

Comment: as this is related to style you may also consider using CSS text-transform capitalize, you have less control over how capitalization is performed and there may be browser issues, but you could easily change to uppercase and lowercase, remove it ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can capitalise the first letter of a string like this:

```
var capitalised = yourString.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + yourString.slice(1);
```

Alternatively:

```
var capitalised = yourString.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + yourString.substring(1);
```

Assuming that your `document.write` call contains the string you want to capitalise:

```
var yourString = str.substr(str2.length,(str.length - str2.length - 1 ) );
var capitalised = yourString.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + yourString.slice(1);
```

Comment: why slice and not substring(1)

Comment: substring reads better. It is more understandable http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2243824/what-is-the-difference-between-string-slice-and-string-substring-in-javascript

Comment: Perhaps, although it's really a matter of opinion. There are slight differences in the way `slice` and `substring` work, but in this case either will suffice. I've added `substring` as an alternative though.

Answer (score 1):

If you have LoDash on hand, this can also be achieved using [_.capitalize](https://lodash.com/docs#capitalize)

```
_.capitalize('FRED');
// => 'Fred'
```