# Parse string in given format to date

Tags: javascript, datetime

I want to parse date in the format ddMMyyhhmm (eg 2804121530 representing 28th April 2012, 3:30 PM) to javascript Date() object.

Is there any oneliner solution to it? I'm looking for something of the kind:

```
var date = Date.parse('2804121530', 'ddMMyyhhmm');
```

or

```
var date = new Date('2804121530', 'ddMMyyhhmm');
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: There is no such built-in function, but you can have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/476105/how-can-i-convert-string-to-datetime-with-format-specification-in-javascript)

Comment: Hi bellow link can be useful for you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/formatting-a-date-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A useful library here is [DateJs](http://www.datejs.com/). Just add a reference:

```
<script src="http://datejs.googlecode.com/files/date.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and use [Date.parseExact](http://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/APIDocumentation#parseExact):

```
var dateStr = '2804121530';
var date = Date.parseExact(dateStr, 'ddMMyyHHmm');
```

Answer (score 2):

For a fast solution you can brake that string into pieces and create date from those pieces

```
function myDateFormat(myDate){
    var day = myDate[0]+''+myDate[1];
    var month = parseInt(myDate[2]+''+myDate[3], 10) - 1;
    var year = '20'+myDate[4]+''+myDate[5];
    var hour = myDate[6]+''+myDate[7];
    var minute = myDate[8]+''+myDate[9];
    return new Date(year,month,day,hour,minute,0,0);
}

var myDate = myDateFormat('2804121530');
```

or a simper solution:

```
function myDateFormat(myDate){
    return new Date(('20'+myDate.slice(4,6)),(parseInt(myDate.slice(2,4), 10)-1),myDate.slice(0,2),myDate.slice(6,8),myDate.slice(8,10),0,0);
}
var myDate = myDateFormat('2804121530');
```

Comment: You need to `+ 1` the month (it is zero based), so you have to parse at least that (sorry - -1 `:/`). Also, you could use [string.slice](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2243824/7586) to remove some ugliness.

Comment: added `-1` :) because `Date` starts from 0

Answer (score 0):

```
(new Date(1381344723000)).toUTCString()
```

Correct me if 'm worng...

Comment: James has the *string* `'2804121530'`, so I don't think this helps much.

Comment: Right, and I guess the param is seconds/milliseconds since epoch. In my case it's a date string in the format ddMMyyhhmm