# How to get head and body tags as a string from html string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Hey i have an html string i'm having trouble getting the tags from.

I have tried alot of stuff, here are some :

```
var head = $("head",$(htmlString)).html();
var body = $("body",$(htmlString)).html();
var head = $("head",htmlString).html();
var body = $("body",htmlString).html();
var head = $("head",$(htmlString).html()).html();
var body = $("body",$(htmlString).html()).html();
var head = htmlString.match(/<head[^>]*>([^<]+)<\/head>/);
var body = htmlString.match(/<body[^>]*>([^<]+)<\/body>/);
var head = jQuery('<div/>').append(htmlString).find('head').html();
var body = jQuery('<div/>').append(htmlString).find('body').html();
```

Any many other tries besides that. All of this return "undefined" or "" or jquery object when i try loging it to console.

Could anyone tell me how can i get the body and head tags as a string?

**Prefered with jQuery/JS and not regex**

Comment: `$(htmlString).find("body");`?

Comment: At least the first three work like a charm for me. So what is the problem here? Any error messages? Not the output you are expecting (if so, please show us `htmlString`)?

Comment: sp00m not working and @Andreas no error messages i try login hte htmlString and see "undefined " or some object. `htmlString` is really long but i'm not sure the browser interpets it as string could this be related?

Comment: Show us the string please ([jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net)). For your question. Just use a simple string to test `<html><head><title>foo</title><body>body</body></html>`

Comment: I Added the string to the question and i tried in my code using the test html and same result.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Try Below Code:**

```
var head = htmlString.match(/<head[^>]*>[\s\S]*<\/head>/gi);
var body = htmlString.match(/<body[^>]*>[\s\S]*<\/body>/gi);
```

Comment: Well this does work for me, in case i won't find a jQuery solution i'll use this, as i suspect it could fail on some cases where the body tag could contain values etc. Am i wrong?

Answer (score 5):

Since you have well formed HTML, you can create a document and select nodes from it:

```
var doc = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(htmlstring,"text/html");
console.log(doc.head.outerHTML);
console.log(doc.body.outerHTML);
```

Here is a demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/X3Uq2/

In Chrome, you can't use a `"text/html"` content type, so you have to make an XML document and use `getElementsByTagName`:

```
var s = new XMLSerializer();
var doc = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(data,"text/xml");
console.log(s.serializeToString(doc.getElementsByTagName("head")[0]));
console.log(s.serializeToString(doc.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/X3Uq2/2/

Comment: my html is not in the document it's in a string!

Comment: @eric.itzhak Fixed, added demo

Comment: i will not always have well formed HTML, does this change anything? i have no control on what the HTML will be inside htmlString.

Comment: And this code returning "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'head' of null " though htmlString is defined!

Comment: @eric.itzhak Please post the exact code you are using to implement this. As I have demonstrated in the fiddle, this approach works.

Comment: I disagree because your fiddle doesn't work for me, returns the same error. i'm using Chrome

Comment: And yet again i get the errors. at firts i get `Object #<Console> has no method 'clear' ` but when i remove the clear it gives the error i mentioned before.

Comment: @eric.itzhak Works in Firefox. I'll try to figure out what is going on with Chrome.

Comment: @eric.itzhak Yes it does. For IE7 and earlier there is a slightly different syntax.

Comment: The Chrome version will only work if the document is valid XHTML, right? If it's HTML but not XHTML wouldn't this break?

Comment: @MattBrowne Yes, but you can make it work using the extension [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/DOMParser#DOMParser_HTML_extension_for_other_browsers). It enables use of the `text/html` document type for other browsers.

Comment: Thanks...is there any advantage to doing this for a simple case like grabbing the entire `<head>` or `<body>`? Since I'm appending the contents of `<body>` to the current page, the HTML has to be parsed anyway, so would your method perhaps be more efficient than a regex in my case...or does it not matter?

Comment: @MattBrowne The reason I suggested this is because regex is fundamentally the wrong querying tool for extracting parts of a DOM. I'm not the first person to say this, and it has been echoed many times on the internet. Imagine trying to hack into Google's databases to try to retrieve a search result. Using the pre-existing DOM parser is more robust, efficient, and readable than trying to write a regex based parser that mimics functionality the environment already provides.

Comment: @Asad I know what you're talking about; in fact I was very entertained by [this rant](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/560114). But in such a simple case like this, would the regexp to find the contents of `<body>` ever fail? Given the simple goal here, I'm more concerned with performance and practicality.

Comment: @MattBrowne The only way of knowing whether it would fail would be to try and come up with HTML that can break it. HTML is notorious for working even when badly formed, so for example I could have an unclosed `body` tag that wouldn't be detected by that regex, but would still work perfectly in the page. If you're not worried about cases like that, you can use a regex. My point is that the only reliable (and easiest) way of knowing how the browser will break a certain string of HTML into logical segments is to simply ask the browser how it will break the string of HTML into logical segments.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I know that my HTML will be well-formed. So I guess it's more performant to use a regexp in my case, no?

Comment: Depends. If you need to later add the body (which I'm assuming comprises most of the document) to the page, it is actually more efficient to use this method, since you can then append the already parsed DOM Element to the page directly. If most of the document is going to be discarded, the regex is probably faster. In both cases, this is unnecessary micro-optimisation, unless your document is absolutely gigantic.

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascript [slice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2243824/what-is-the-difference-between-string-slice-and-string-substring) method this way:

```js
var html = '<!DOCTYPE html>'+
'<html>'+
  '<head>' +
    '<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" /> '+
    '<title></title>' +
  '</head>' +
  '<body>Some Text!</body>' +
'</html>'
var bEnd, bStart;
bStart = html.indexOf("<body");
bEnd = html.indexOf("</body");
var body = html.slice(bStart, bEnd);
console.log(body);
```

Answer (score 0):

may be this can help you

```
var head = jQuery('<div/>').append(htmlString).find('head').html();

var body = jQuery('<div/>').append(htmlString).find('body').html();
```

Comment: Still login it gives "undefined"

Answer (score -4):

It's really simple:

> JQuery: $(head) 
>  Native js: document.head

If you wanted to get html of this tag:

> In JQuery: $(head).html(); 
> Native js: document.head.innerHtml

You find nice JQuery refernece here: http://visualjquery.com