# jQuery variable issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

Quick overview, when a user clicks a link with an anchor tag it opens the closest hidden div to that anchor on the destination page.

My problem seems pretty basic I just can't figure it out.

Why does this work(specifying the variable to set the height to, in this case height7):

```
var height7 =  100;

if(window.location.hash) {
      var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1); 
      $('a[name='+hash+']').closest('[id^="option"]').show();
      $('a[name='+hash+']').closest('[id^="option"]').height(height7);
} else {
      // No hash found
}
```

And this not work(in this case trying to build the name of the div i want to open, place it in a variable and passing it to the height() function exactly as above, for some reason it doesn't accept the variable):

```
if(window.location.hash) {
     var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1); 
     var option_name = $('a[name='+hash+']').closest('[id^="option"]').attr("id");
     var hash_div_height_id = "height" + option_name.substring(6);
     alert(hash_div_height_id);
     $('a[name='+hash+']').closest('[id^="option"]').show();
     $('a[name='+hash+']').closest('[id^="option"]').height(hash_div_height_id);
} else {
      // No hash found
}
```

Comment: I think that you should use `.slice` instead of `.substring` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2243824/what-is-the-difference-between-string-slice-and-string-substring-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're assigning different values in each case:

```
$('a[name='+hash+']').closest('[id^="option"]').height(height7); //height = 100

$('a[name='+hash+']').closest('[id^="option"]').height(hash_div_height_id); //height = "height" + option_name.substring(6)
```

Comment: Thanks, should have realized that.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be **assigning a string value**

```
var hash_div_height_id = "height" + option_name.substring(6);

     .height(hash_div_height_id);
```

Where as it is supposed to be a number.

So `hash_div_height_id` will be something like `height` + `something`

When setting a `height` property it expects

> An integer representing the number of pixels, or an integer with an
>   optional unit of measure appended (as a string).

Comment: Thanks for identifying my issue. Now I have the slightly bigger problem of figuring out how to take the string "height7" and somehow using that to find out the value of the variable height7.

Comment: It is difficult to say without taking a look at the `HTML`