# How do I access or replicate string value of an object?

Tags: javascript, object

For example, I'm trying to isolate the first 5 characters of window.location.

```
var ltype, string = 'string';
console.log(window.location);         // file:///C:/for example
console.log(typeof window.location);  // [OBJECT] 
lType=window.location.substr(0,5);    // 'not a function' (quite so)
string=window.location;
lType=string.substr(0,5);             // fails similarly
```

**Q1:** Can I somehow 'bind' substr() to window.location?

I can see that `string=window.location` replicates a reference and not
a value, so

**Q2:** How can a separate, discrete copy of a complex structure such as an object or an array be created [without using `JSON.stringify()` or `JSON.parse()` - which is what I am presently resorting to]?

Comment: Copy object: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/most-elegant-way-to-clone-a-javascript-object

Comment: Get part of a string: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2243824/what-is-the-difference-between-string-slice-and-string-substring-in-javascript

Comment: `window.location.toString().substr(...)` should solve your problem.

Comment: so much help! thank-you. All sorted now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`window.location` [is an object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.location), so you can't use string functions on it - as you've noticed. In order to get the actual location as a string (to perform string operations on it), you'll need to convert it to a string somehow.

- `window.location.href` is a property provided by the object itself.
- `window.location.toString()` is a method on all JavaScript objects, overridden here.

However, ***beware of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)***. It looks to me like you're trying to retrieve the protocol (the `http:` bit) of the URI. There's a property for that too - `window.location.protocol`.

```
lType = window.location.protocol;
```

You should use that - it's more robust (consider `https://` or, worse, `ftp://`...).

Comment: And when I accept your answer it seems to unaccept the previous answer. ??? I better go read the manual again

Comment: @MattArnold `1` That's a separate question (that, furthermore, [has already been asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/most-elegant-way-to-clone-a-javascript-object)). `2` There can be only one accepted answer. (Mine? Pretty please?)

Comment: I've read the manual, seen the light, leaving the green tick with you

Answer (score 2):

try

```
string = window.location.href.toString();
```

instead of

```
string=window.location;
```

Because window.location will return object not a string.

Comment: Quite right: I had tried to to list the properies of the object using the famous old 'showProps' exec from XUL School. For some reason it gave no result when used against window.location.