# jQuery .Slice clarification

Tags: jquery, slice

Could someone please explain to me the supposed purpose of .Slice in this piece of code? How can you select a subset of padding-bottom? Thanks a lot.

```
$(this).bind('click', function(){
      var tid = $(this).attr('id');
      tid = tid.replace('play-button-', '');
      playheight = parseInt($('#play-view-' + tid, 10).height());
      playpadding = parseInt($('#play-view-' + tid, 10).css('padding-bottom').slice(0, -2));
      var flex_height = playheight + playpadding;
      setTimeout(function(){
        $('.flex-viewport').animate({height: flex_height});
      },200);
    });
```

--- Alternative without using slice ----

```
    $(this).bind('click', function(){
      var tid = $(this).attr('id');
      tid = tid.replace('playlist-button-', '');
      playheight = $('#playlist-display-' + tid).height();
      playheight = parseInt(playheight, 10);
      playpadding = ('#playlist-display-' + tid);
      playpadding = $(playpadding).css('padding-bottom');
      if (playpadding != null) {
        playpadding = parseInt(playpadding, 10);
        flex_height = playheight + playpadding;
      } else {
        flex_height = playheight;
      }
        setTimeout(function(){
        $('.flex-viewport').animate({height: flex_height});
      },200);
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slice on a string takes a substring and returns it.

In this case it gets the padding value and removes the last two characters (the units - for example px or em) so the ParseInt can parse the string as an integer.

`'10px'.slice(0,-2)` will return '**10**'

You can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2243824/what-is-the-difference-between-string-slice-and-string-substring-in-javascript) for some differences from the substring function:

Comment: Ah okay. That makes sense. Except that doesn't parseInt itself remove everything that's not an integer? This code doesn't actually work and I thought it had to do with slice. So I edited my question to include a work around that does work. Is there any advantage to using slice over this?

Comment: Yeah parseInt does that. It will parse any numbers before a non-numeric character, so it should be fine without it. I can't say why slice was used in this case, maybe it was included as a precaution in case some client browser had not implemented parseInt in the same way.