# string.slice() with arguments in loop trouble

Tags: javascript, slice

I was having fun with string methods and approached an issue while using `slice` on a string in the loop:

```
var sentence = document.querySelector('.newClass').textContent.split(' '),
    blank = '_________________________';

for(var i = 0; i < sentence.length; i += 1) {
    console.log(sentence[i] + blank.substring(blank.length, sentence[i].length) + i); //works
    console.log(sentence[i] + blank.slice(blank.length, sentence[i].length) + i); //???
}
```

**CODE:** http://jsfiddle.net/cachaito/Jxzd5/

I was sure `string.slice()` works same as `string.substring()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some subtle differences, most of which are described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2243824/what-is-the-difference-between-string-slice-and-string-substring-in-javascript). However, the behavior you're seeing is because `blank.length` is always greater than `sentence[i].length`, and `substring` swaps the arguments in this case. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring):

> If `indexA` is larger than `indexB`, then the effect of `substring` is as if the two arguments were swapped; for example, `str.substring(1, 0) == str.substring(0, 1)`.

But [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) doesn't do this. If the first argument is larger than the second, the result will be an empty string (assuming both are positive).

Try this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < sentence.length; i += 1) {
    console.log(sentence[i] + blank.substring(blank.length, sentence[i].length) + i); //works
    console.log(sentence[i] + blank.slice(sentence[i].length, blank.length) + i); //works
}
```

Or even this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < sentence.length; i += 1) {
    console.log(sentence[i] + blank.substring(blank.length, sentence[i].length) + i);
    console.log(sentence[i] + blank.slice(0, -sentence[i].length) + i);
}
```

Comment: That's a brilliant answer! Thank You for explanation and link for 'What is the difference between String.slice and String.substring in JavaScript?' article :-)