# JQuery: Cut off div text after 4 characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, text

I only want to display the first four characters of a div, but it seems to be more difficult than needed and google isn't very helpful. Different variations of this don't seem to work:

```
$("#div").html(this.html().substring(0,4));
```

I really want to avoid having an extra variable in there that stores the text first.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use a callback for the `.html()`,

```
$('#div').html(function(i, currentHtml) {
  return currentHtml.substring(0, 4);
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/exvS8/)**

You can also use `.text()` in this case  if the div consists only of plain text.

```
$("#div").text(function(i, currentText) {
    return currentText.substring(0, 4);
});
```

---

Refer :

**[Slice vs Substring](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2243835/3639582)**

Turns out substring is relatively faster.

**[JsPerf test : slice() vs substring() vs others](https://jsperf.com/slice-vs-substr-vs-substring-methods-long-string/3)**

Answer (score 2):

If the div elements contains any HTML (html elements) then `.html()` return  the it's as a string. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/mDFKX/1/)

**Note: (It's completely depend on the inner content of you div)**

If you want to truncate the plain text, you should use `.text()` instead of using `.html()`

Try this:

```
$("#div").text(function(){   
    return $(this).text().substring(0,4);
});
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mDFKX/)

Comment: Yes, there are some HTML elements in this case, but thanks for the addition!

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$("#div").html(function(){
    return $(this).html().substring(0,4)
    });
```

It will count space also...If any there.

Like DIV have  "test four 3" will give you output "test"

Answer (score 1):

Use **slice()** for this purpose :

```
$("#div").text(function(){   
    return $(this).text().slice(0,4);
});
```