# Limit $scope variable display to certain number of characters

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm building an app with angularJS, i have a `$scope` variable called `description` and it is basically just a long description of something in my database.

Is there a simple way to limit the number of characters that is outputted when i do `{{description}}`?

Or can it only be done through a separate $scope variable?

I would ideally want to limit the number of characters outputted by this $scope variable to 100.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to slice/trim a $scope variable in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37552570/how-to-slice-trim-a-scope-variable-in-angularjs)

Comment: The proposed duplicate does not apply because the question asks how to do it without creating a separate variable. - [From review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/22986900).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AngularJS has a built-in [`limitTo`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo) filter. In your case, it outputs a string limited to the specified number of characters. You can use it as follows:

```
<span>{{description | limitTo:100}}</span>
```

If you wish to show ellipsis when the string is trimmed, you can do something like that:

```
<span>{{description | limitTo:100}}{{description.length > 100 ? '&#8230;' : ''}}</span>
```

But, of course, nobody prevents you from doing all this job in your controller. Here I've presented more angular-ish way.