# Javascript How to get first three characters of a string

Tags: javascript, string

This may duplicate with previous topics but I can't find what I really need.

I want to get a first three characters of a string. For example:

```
var str = '012123';
console.info(str.substring(0,3));  //012
```

I want the output of this string '012' but I don't want to use subString or something similar to it because I need to use the original string for appending more characters '45'. With substring it will output 01245 but what I need is 01212345.

Comment: In this case, when it's a string, you'd be getting the characters, not necessarily digits. But I'm confused - you *are* getting the first 3 characters of the string. So what are you trying to do?

Comment: Strings are immutable.

Comment: `substring` will return a new string `012`, but `str` will still be equal to `012123`. `substring` will not change the contents of `str`.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show how you are trying to use the results. Calling `.substring()` (or `.slice()` or `.substr()`) doesn't change the original string at all, it returns a *new* string. `str` doesn't change unless you explicitly overwrite it with `str = str.substring(0,3)`.

Comment: The above commenters are correct-- the method just returns what you want without changing the original string.  So you can store the returned value in a variable like `strFirstThree = str.substring(0,3)` and still have access to `str` in its entirety.

Answer (score 179, accepted):

```js
var str = '012123';
var strFirstThree = str.substring(0,3);

console.log(str); //shows '012123'
console.log(strFirstThree); // shows '012'
```

Now you have access to both.

Answer (score 30):

[`slice(begin, end)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) works on strings, as well as arrays. It returns a string representing the substring of the original string, from `begin` to `end` (`end` not included) where `begin` and `end` represent the index of characters in that string.

```js
const string = "0123456789";
console.log(string.slice(0, 2)); // "01"
console.log(string.slice(0, 8)); // "01234567"
console.log(string.slice(3, 7)); // "3456"
```

#### See also:

- [What is the difference between String.slice and String.substring?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2243824/247696)

Comment: And if you omit the `end` then it will give you back the rest of the string from the `start`. With `string` from above: `console.log(string.slice(7)); // "789"`