# Javascript create filter for gallery

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a filterable gallery, but now It is only showing the right image when the whole title matches the input value. But I want to filter on seperated letters. Here I wrote a function: `

```
filterList (filterText) {
    var updatedList = this.props.array; 
    return updatedList.filter(function(item){
        var split = item.name.split("");
        console.log(split, filterText);
        return split === filterText;
    });
  }
```

Now it show me the seperated item.name like this: `["p","h","o","t","o","","1"]`
Instead of Photo 1 I want to filter on seperated letters.

Here is a link to the codePen: [LINK](http://codepen.io/smgjrein/pen/ALbVyo?editors=0010)
`

Comment: That doesn't make much sense. Whether you filter on the whole string, or individual letters, the match is exactly the same; all letters in the array must match. If you want to do partial matches, you'll need to do some more work, probably with `substring` or `slice` to get the minimum number of letters to match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to compare the input value with a substring of the whole title that has the same length. Here is an example:

```
filterList (filterText) {
    var len = filterText.length,
        updatedList = this.props.array;

    return updatedList.filter(function(item){
        var split = item.name.slice(0, len);
        console.log(split, filterText);
        return split === filterText;
    });
}
```

Comment: I don't get it we give as end variable to the slice function the length of the input value. But how does it work?

Comment: `String.slice(0, x)` is to get the first x characters and return it as a new string. `.slice()` is similar to `.substring()`, but also has a few differences. Check out [more details here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2243824/what-is-the-difference-between-string-slice-and-string-substring)

Answer (score 0):

My first guess is this:

```
filterList (filterText) {
    var updatedList = this.props.array; 
    return updatedList.filter(function(item){
        var split = item.name.split(" ");
        console.log(split, filterText);
        return split === filterText;
    });
  }
```

maybe if you give us an example 'filterText' and return how its suposed to be it would be easier.

Comment: @Beginnerprogrammer Please include all relevant code as a [mcve] in the question itself, not on a third party site. See [ask].