# delete characters from certain character in string

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to delete (or hide) characters in a string, for example: 
I have string with 20 characters and I need to delete all characters from 15. 
P.S. I got one idea, but don't think that its correct: create two paragraphs with different classes, one paragraph with 15 characters, second one doesn't matter and delete/hide second paragraph
example:

```
    var count;
    count = $('#mydiv').text().length;
    if (count => 15) { 
    }
```

Comment: Hard to make much sense out of what exactly it is you are trying to accomplish.what your html looks like and what expected results are. Please take a few minutes to read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: have a look at [substr](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substr.asp)

Comment: Dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952924/javascript-chop-slice-trim-off-last-character-in-string

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the [substring()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp) method.

```
var text = "this is a super long string.";
var shortText = text.substring(0, 15);
// shortText now is "this is a super"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `string.substr`

```
var str = "Hello world!";
var res = str.substr(0, 5); // returns Hello
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `slice` function - `string.slice(start, end)`

`var res = str.slice(0, 16);`

Comment: worth noting - [`difference between String.slice and String.substr?`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2243835/104380)

Comment: why did you comment my link again and said what I said already?

Comment: i usually use slice for strings and splice for array

Comment: sorry vsync, i commented my answer not your comment!

Answer (score 0):

## Via CSS:

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/truncate-string-with-ellipsis/

```
.truncate {
  width: 250px; // or any other width
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

## Via [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs#truncate):

```
_.truncate('hi-diddly-ho there, neighborino');
// => 'hi-diddly-ho there, neighbo...'

_.truncate('hi-diddly-ho there, neighborino', {
  'length': 24,
  'separator': ' '
});
// => 'hi-diddly-ho there,...'

_.truncate('hi-diddly-ho there, neighborino', {
  'length': 24,
  'separator': /,? +/
});
// => 'hi-diddly-ho there...'

_.truncate('hi-diddly-ho there, neighborino', {
  'omission': ' [...]'
});
// => 'hi-diddly-ho there, neig [...]'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know what you want to remove then just replace it with .replace() not sure exactly what you mean by hide characters. It seems all answers are possible solutions to your question though https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take a look at the substring support page:
https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring

jsfiddle with substring use:
https://jsfiddle.net/zdLdk6Lj/

```
var divtext = $('#mydiv').text();

$('#mydiv').text(divtext.substring(0,15));
```